# Git - best practices (in general, and from a perspective of former SVN user.)

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

Recently I have learned the basics concepts of Git. We did use a bit of git-svn to get familiar with using it. I would like to start my first "true" project on git along with my friends.

Therefore I would like to ask you what are the best practices of using Git in general, and if there are any pitfalls that SVN familiar developer my get into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collaboration among more than one developer is probably best done using a central "bare" repository, which is roughly analogous to a repository in Subversion. Sharing changes between two or more people with only their own repositories, is difficult and prone to error. Also, using a central repository will feel more comfortable coming from a Subversion background.

One great thing about Git is that you can easily have more than one "common" repository. I have my development set up so I keep a set of bare repositories on one server that I usually interact with ("origin" for most of my projects), but for some projects I also push the whole thing up to GitHub. I don't have to choose which one is the single central repository, I can pull and work from the GitHub repository and later push to my own copy.

Answer (score 2):

There are pitfalls to thinking that Git is SVN with a bad accent.  This [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457927/git-workflow-and-rebase-vs-merge-questions) demonstrates two pitfalls in Git which could make sense in SVN:

1. Thinking that `rebase` in Git should be replaced with `merge`.  Merging with someone else's changes will sometimes result in many unnecessary merge conflicts that `rebase` avoids.
2. Pushing a feature branch to a remote repository and then merging there gets even worse results.

Another major pitfall is expressed well in the [Git FAQs](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/GitFaq) under "Unexpected Beharviour":

```
    A quick rule of thumb is to *never* push into a repository 
    that has a work tree attached to it, until you know what you are doing.
```

Somewhere in the Man pages it is gently explained that this can "lead to unexpected results." Like losing all of someone else's work.

This [Git SVN Crash Course](http://git.or.cz/course/svn.html) will ease your transition to Git while still thinking in SVN.

Comment: Ehm, rebase gives more conflicts, as each of the commits are adapted to where you rebase to (and you have to remember how the source should  look at that point), while a merge does all the conflict resolution for all the commits, so I would say always do merge instead of rebases until you know how rebase works and when it is safe to use.

Answer (score 1):

Getting an account on [GitHub](http://github.com) and using it to maintain some working, non-essential code is a great way to find your own best way to do it. I've found the [Network Visualizer](http://github.com/blog/39-say-hello-to-the-network-graph-visualizer) very helpful for "seeing" what's happening as I try various things with git.

Comment: "gitk" works at least as well as this one and don't require to push the changes.