# A new commit to git parent branch and propagate these changes to child branches

Tags: git

I have a branch feat-1 based off develop.
I did some commits in feat-1, and created pull request to merge feat-1 into develop.
While waiting for the pull request to be merged, I created a new branch feat-2 based off feat-1 to work on a new feature that depends on code in feat-1.
My work in feat-2 was done, and I needed to work on a new feature that depends on feat-2. So I created a new branch feat-3 based off feat-2.

```
develop
        \
         feat-1
                \
                    feat-2
                            \
                            feat-3
```

Now, there are some changes that need to be done in feat-1.
These changes would conflict with feat-2 and feat-3.
When I commit this changes in feat-1, how do I propagate those changes to feat-2 and feat-3?

If I merge feat-1 into feat-2 then I would have to merge feat-2 into feat-3, and so on.
That way I may have to handle the same conflicts several times.

Is there a way that I just have to handle the conflicts once?

Comment: Merge branch by branch or rebase with `--update-refs `

Comment: Using `--update-refs` worked like a charm! Care to post an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your "newest" branch already contains *all* commits of your other branches, [`--update-refs`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---update-refs) of `git rebase` might come in handy:

```
git checkout feat1
# make changes
git commit -m 'changes which need to go to all branches'
git rebase --update-refs feat1 feat3
```

This will update branches `feat2` and `feat3` to now depend on the new commit(s) introduced on branch `feat1`. It will only work if `feat2` does not contain additional commits that are not in `feat3` (commits of `feat2` must be a strict subset of `feat3` for it to work).

The usual disclaimers about `git rebase` apply: it creates new commits with new commit hashes, force-pushing is required, don't do it for shared history.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way that I just have to handle the conflicts once?

**Yes absolutely**, by using the explicit onto three argument form of rebase.

## Test repo

To recreate your scenario I created a test repository which has a changelog file that each commit adds a line to so that `feat-3` at the end contains:

```markdown
# Changelog

## Unreleased

* Changelog added.
* Added feature 1.
* Added feature 2.
* Added feature 3.
```

and to create a conflict a readme is added on `develop` after `feat-1` was branched out:

```markdown
# Changelog

## Unreleased

* Changelog added.
* Added readme file.
```

[image: gitk --all screenshot]

## Step 1

> some changes that need to be done in feat-1.

For instance rebasing `feat-1` on top of the latest `develop`.

But before starting any rebasing, let's create a couple of branches to hold references to what branches were before the rebase started.

```bash
$ git branch feat-1.old feat-1
$ git branch feat-2.old feat-2
$ git branch feat-3.old feat-3
```

Rebasing of `feat-1` on top of `develop` will of course results in a conflict because both branches has added different things at the same place:

```
$ git rebase develop feat-1
Auto-merging CHANGELOG.md
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in CHANGELOG.md
error: could not apply 0a7176f... Added feature 1
hint: Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
hint: "git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
hint: You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
hint: To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply 0a7176f... Added feature 1
$
```

**You should never, never, never, never, ever settle for anything less than a tool with proper 3-way merge support to resolve such conflicts.** My favourite is [using KDiff3](https://github.com/hlovdal/git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3)

[image: KDiff3 screenshot]

where in this particular case, the correct resolvement was accepting B's change and then C's change.

```bash
Update CHANGELOG.md with merge result? [YyNnQq] (y): 
...
$ git rebase --continue
...
$
```

So `feat-1` is now updated and conflict resolved, and preferably this is the last time we need to deal with that conflict again...

## Step 2

...and the good news is that using rebase onto three argument form we can achieve that. Starting with `feat-2`.

[image: gitk --all screenshot]

Since `feat-2` contains the old commit from `feat-1` and git thinks that the common ancestor is the parent to that commit, then that conflict would re-appear with a plain `git rebase feat-1 feat-2`.

[But we are not bound by what the version control system thinks is the common base, we can chose whatever we want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2351522/23118). This is basically what rebase onto three argument form does.

So for `feat-2` the history past `feat-1.old` is not of particular interest and is just incidental, and we can tell git that when doing a rebase:

```bash
$ git rebase --onto feat-1 feat-1.old feat-2
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/feat-2.
$
```

So the command tells git rebase on top of `feat-1` all commits from (not including) `feat-1.old` to (including) `feat-2`, completely ignoring<sup>1</sup> the conflict contained in the old feat-1 commit.

## Step 3

`feat-3` is just the same as `feat-2`:

```bash
$ git rebase --onto feat-2 feat-2.old feat-3
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/feat-3.
$
```

[image: gitk --all screenshot]

## Step 4

After the rebases, you ought to run [git-test](https://github.com/mhagger/git-test) on all the new commits.

After everything is verified you can delete all the feat-*.old branches.

---

<sup>1</sup> I was actually surprised today that this did not trigger a conflict since the lines changed are so close. It must have been changed from before when I think changes within +-3 lines would trigger a conflict. But in that case using KDiff3 would have resolved those automatically since it is a bit more aggressive in its strategy of resolving conflicts and as long as it is not the same line that is modified, KDiff3 accepts all changes (which normally is nice but it can also occasionally accept too much).

Answer (score 0):

you rebase `feat-2` on `feat-1` and potentially that fixes the conflict so you can rebase `feat-3` onto `feat-2` without anything to fix (or still, resolving conflicts in the process)

If you dont care about linearity of git history, you can either cherry-pick commit from `feat-1` onto rest of your branches, or merge `feat-1` into rest of your branches.

> Is there a way that I just have to handle the conflicts once?

not really as all of the branches contains its onw unique commit history, therfore you cannot apply commit in "root" of the branch and expect it to be applied backwards (because it would be "before" following changes. Even if you would remove `feat-1`, rest of the branches will hold commits that were in `feat-1` intact as it were

You have to apply modifications branch by branch.