# What is the correct way to manage two feature branches which depend on parts of eachother?

Tags: git, branch, rebase

I have two git branches being developed concurrently: `foo`, and `bar`. After several commits on each, `bar` requires an object implemented within `foo`. Several commits after this point, `foo` requires an object implemented by `bar`.

What is the best (cleanest, most workable) way to resolve this?

I initially went with rebasing, but after realising that created a desync with the remote requiring a pull (even though the remote previously was behind the local branch), I'm not so sure it's a good solution.

I assume that due to the nature of `foo` and `bar` being interdependent, a squash-merge is not feasible at all. Though, since they're otherwise separate features, I didn't think merging one into the other before merging into main was appropriate.

Comment: Can you separate those 2 common requirements into their own branches? You could merge them separately and then have the original 2 branches rebased on top of the upstream branch after the other 2 branches had been merged

Comment: `git rebase --update-refs`

Comment: @eftshift0 I could, but it feels a bit overkill to have an entire branch for what amounts to 1-2 commits

Comment: @Guildenstern Could you elaborate? I read the documentation but I'm honestly confused as to what update-refs does

Comment: I think that the fact that they are _small_ is not that important if the outcome will get you in a more organized fashion..... _a branch_ in `git`, in the end, is just a pointer to a commit, so it's not like you are polluting your repo somehow by using more branches.

Comment: @eftshift0 My concern was with squash and merge, but I think it was born more out of misunderstanding than any legitimate reasoning. You're correct, and I have now begun to untangle the branches via cherry picking. Thanks

Comment: It's simpler if you model this as one branch needing the other instead of a mutual dependence. And in that case you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75273904/1725151).