# How to merge specific revision of my branch to other branch GitHUB?

Tags: git, github, git-svn

In GitHub, I have two branches working and master branch. Now I wanted to merge specific revision of working branch to the master branch.

Can somebody explain me how I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you cannot directly do that on the GitHub (remote) side, you can:

- git clone your GitHub repo
- some some cherry-picking ([as in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627953/git-cherry-pick-and-datamodel-integrity/2628915#2628915)) (or [some `rebase --onto`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994463/how-to-cherry-pick-a-range-of-commits-and-merge-into-another-branch/1994491#1994491)) between your two branches (from `working` to `master`)
- push back the updated `master` branch to GitHub