# Git merge commits between branches

Tags: git, version-control

I've got two branches. Lets call them A & B for now. I want to selectively copy something like 20 commits from A to B. Is there any efficient way to do this?

I know I can git cherry-pick commits one at a time but can I do 20 all at once? This is assuming the 20 commits aren't together and there are commits in between them that I do not want copied over.

Example. Branch A commits

> 4->5->6->7

Branch B

> 1->2->3->8

I want to copy 4,5,7 over to B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rather `rebase --interactive A` onto B, because cherry-picking introduce duplicate commits, which is generally not a good idea.
See "[Git cherry pick and datamodel integrity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627953/git-cherry-pick-and-datamodel-integrity/2628915#2628915)".

That being said, you can specify sets of commits and multiple commits in a `git cherry-pick` command. Separate each commits by a space, and look at how specifying said commits in [gitrevision](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can pass as many commits as you want to `git cherry-pick`

```
$ git checkout B
$ git cherry-pick A~3 A~2 A
```

Will do what you describe in your example.