# How could I use a different strategy for just one commit in a rebase?

Tags: git, rebase

Given this:

```
master  A---B---G---H---I
             \
branch        C---D---E---F
```

Is there anyway to get to the following, but using `-X theirs` **only for the C commit**?

```
master  A---B---G---H---I
                         \
branch                    C'--D'--E'--F'
```

*(I've created a branch for migrating a big solution from VS2008 to VS2010. The first commit on the branch was the one that changed all the project files. Now I would like to update the branch to get the latest changes, but without having to manually merge any conflicts arising from tool-generated code)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to:

- merge first `C` to `master`, using one the [the `merge --strategy=theirs` detailed in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911794/git-command-for-making-one-branch-like-another/4912267#4912267).
- then `git rebase master` (which shouldn't repeat commit `C`, since it has already been merged and is identical to the `C` of `branch`).

Comment: @Benjol: which strategy did you use for the first merge?

Comment: `merge ours` to tmp branch, then ffw merge back the other way. TBH, in the intervening period I also found an alternative (SmartGit lets you block-resolve a group of conflicts, choosing ours/theirs).

Answer (score 2):

This obvious rebasing step, pulled straight [from the manuals](http://book.git-scm.com/4_rebasing.html) doesn't work?

```
git checkout branch
git rebase master
```

Comment: No, because I'm looking to use a specific strategy on **just one commit** (admittedly, this may not even be logically possible, I'm not sure).

Comment: If you want one specific commit (unlike your image that moves all commits after that) you should really cherrypick that one here.

Answer (score 2):

guess, you can use cherry-pick to apply one commit anywhere you want:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick -x C
```

this will apply *C* patch to master. then you can rebase your branch on master, because it will contain *C* inside

```
git checkout master
git rebase master
```

Comment: Yes (+1), this is similar to the method to avoid having a commit repeated twice in the history due to a cherry-pick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627953/git-cherry-pick-and-datamodel-integrity/2628915#2628915

Comment: @radistao, so does cherry-pick automatically have 'theirs' semantics in this case?