# Fixing a conflict without a mergetool during a rebase?

Tags: git, conflict, git-rebase

I'm doing a rebase of master on my branch. There is binary file that conflicts (i expected a conflict) and i just want to accept the one on the branch. If this was a text file i would just open the file with the mergetool and accept everything on my brach but since its binary i can't do that of course. So say the branch name is `branch1` and after doing a rebase:

```
 K:\gitrepo\supplemental [(1c58d85...)|REBASE +0 ~0 -0 !1 | +0 ~0 -0 !1]> g s
# Not currently on any branch.
# You are currently rebasing.
#   (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
#   (use "git rebase --skip" to skip this patch)
#   (use "git rebase --abort" to check out the original branch)
#
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
#
#       both modified:      mybinaryfiles/file.bin
#
```

To accept the file on the branch and finish the rebase would i just:

```
git add .
git rebase --continue
```

To make the question more complete what would i do if i wanted to accept the file from master rather than the branch?

In trying to understand what git actually does during a merge conflict in a rebase....does it actually keep the conflicted file intact and just wants you to confirm that this is correct by doing a `git add`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have both (well, all three including the base version) available in the index. You can retrieve the 'master' version or the 'being-rebased' branch version with:

```
git checkout --ours mybinaryfiles/file.bin
```

and

```
git checkout --theirs mybinaryfiles/file.bin
```

respectively.

Then just `git add mybinaryfiles/file.bin` and `git commit`.

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what i needed. For some reason after i did a rebase --continue i had to do a rebase --skip also but it all seems to have worked out

Answer (score 2):

Git merge supports different merge strategies including `ours` and `theirs`. Git rebase allows to use this merge strategies by using `-m` option. I suggest reading `git-merge` and `git-rebase` manual before you start playing, because there are some quirks about it.

See also:

1. [How do I select a merge strategy for a git rebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945344/selecting-merge-strategy-options-for-git-rebase)
2. [How could I use a different strategy for just one commit in a rebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632678/how-could-i-use-a-different-strategy-for-just-one-commit-in-a-rebase)