# Git keeping separate branches in sync

Tags: git, merge, workflow, branch

I have been working on a branch `new_feature`:

```
A -- B -- C -- D    master
      \    \
       \    1 -- 2 -- 3  new_feature
        \
         E -- F -- G  port
```

Our code base also has an older branch `port` where another developer ported our product to another RDBMS. `port` is not yet ready to be merged back into `master`.

Recently it became necessary to have `new_feature` work in `port`. So I merged those two into a new branch `port/new_feature`, and made some commits there (I, J) to get it working:

```
A -- B -- C -- D    master
      \    \
       \    1 -- 2 -- 3 -- I* -- J* -- K new_feature
        \              \
         E -- F -- G -- H -- I -- J -- K*  port/new_feature
                  port
```

I cherry-picked I and J back into `new_feature` (as I*, J*) because they involved significant refactoring that I wanted to have in `new_feature` too. I have also been making new commits (K) to `new_feature` that need to be brought over to `port/new_feature` (K*).

Going forward, what's the best plan to keep `new_feature` and `port/new_feature` in sync (*but only with respect to new changes*)? Should I keep cherry-picking commits from one to the other (and vice versa)? Or is there a convenient way to do this by merging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cherry-picking is dangerous because of:

- duplicate commits (the next merge will be complicated because Git will try to re-apply `I-J-K` on top of... `I-J-K`).
  That wouldn't be the case if you rebase one branch on top of the other (see "[Git cherry pick and datamodel integrity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627953/git-cherry-pick-and-datamodel-integrity/2628915#2628915)"), but that isn't possible in your case.
- functional dependencies (see "[How to merge a specific commit in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git/881112#881112)"), but I suspect it isn't an issue in your case: `I` and `J` don't depend on  `H`, and can be safely applied to `3`.

Cherry-picking is convenient if you don't intend to merge port and new-feature together.
If that is the case, keep cherry-picking.

Comment: I would ideally like to see all of the branches merged together. But as long as I continue working on my feature and master and port remain unmerged, I guess it makes sense to keep new_feature and port/new_feature as separate branches. Thanks for the good points about cherry-picking -- I look forward to the day when it's all just in master :-)