# git - cherry-pick - HOWTO / WHYTO

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick, git-am

> Problem: You want to test a feature someone has developed, but it only
>   exists in a remote branch which is woefully out of date.

[Source](http://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/Using_Git_Cherry_Pick)

1. How does cherry-pick solve the problem?
2. **Why won't I use git am or git apply?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Problem: You want to test a feature someone has developed, but it only
>   exists in a remote branch which is woefully out of date.

If you merged or rebased, you'd get a bunch of old changes in, possibly conflicting.

With cherry picking, you take one change set, and replay that as a new commit over another branch.

This is useful if you just want one commit onto another branch, without its history.

It's useful to use the `-x` option, so the commit message contains a note where it was cherry picked from.

> Why won't I use git am or git apply?

because git apply is for applying patches (files), and git am for applying series of patches. git cherry-pick applies commits - i.e., commits from your own repo, vs commits you import from other repos.

Answer (score 4):

From [`git help cherry-pick`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html):

> git-cherry-pick - Apply the changes introduced by some existing
>   commits
>
> [...]
>
> Given one or more existing commits, apply the change each one
>   introduces, recording a new commit for each. This requires your
>   working tree to be clean (no modifications from the HEAD commit).

So, when you `cherry-pick` a commit, `git` takes that commit's changes (its `diff`) and tries to apply it on your current working directory, creating a new commit that is equivalent to the one you are `cherry-pick`ing.

It's a way to re-do another commit's changes on a different history line.

Besides taking the changes, `cherry-pick` also preserves the original commit's info like author and that.

Lastly, `cherry-pick` can receive a group of commits to apply, in which case it would act like `cherry-pick`ing them one by one, in chronological order (older first).

Answer (score 2):

> Problem:
>   You want to test a feature someone has developed, but it only exists in a remote branch which is woefully out of date.

It solves the problem because:

- you don't want to merge the old branch including commits which are no longer relevant in your current state of development
- you don't want to rebase your branch on top of an old branch just to get that one commit.
- you won't have to merge back your branch to that old branch

The last point is important because the first drawback of cherry-picking is that it introduces **[duplicate commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627953/git-cherry-pick-and-datamodel-integrity/2628915#2628915)**. But in your case, it doesn't matter.

The other drawback is that the commit you are cherry-picking might have **[functional dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git/881112#881112)** based on previous commits (of that old branch).
In other word, its code works only because of other codes of other older commits (which aren't cherry-picked).
That can be trickier to detect.