# Git branch. How to assign a commit to a branch?

Tags: git, branch, commit

I have two branches. Say, the first one commit's checksum is 11223344, the second one has 55667788. How to assign the commit 55667788 to the first branch?

Comment: You want to apply the changes of the commit of one branch to the other?

Comment: What do you want? Just merge the second branch into the first branch?

Comment: @Arjan, I made it. But I'm bad at git now and don't know what `cherry-pick` means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply want to apply the changes in commit `55667788` to branch `first`, you can just use `cherry-pick`.

```
git checkout first
git cherry-pick 55667788
```

If you are actually after importing all commits that `second` has that `first` doesn't (including `55667788`) you would merge it.

```
git checkout first
git merge --no-ff second
```

The `--no-ff` argument is made clear here

[image]
<sup>(From [nvie.com](http://nvie.com/), [Vincent Driessen](http://nvie.com/about/), post "[**A successful Git branching model**](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)")</sup>

Comment: @RedPlanet beware of cherry-pick dangers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13522664/what-does-cherry-pick-do-exactly-in-git/13524494#13524494