# How could commits be on a branch twice?

Tags: git, github

I have the following Git history:

```
    D-E-A-B-C-A-B-C (feature2)
   /
  *-D-E (feature1)
 /
*-F (develop)
```

I have no idea how  A, B and C ended up on feature2 twice. I have been rebasing feature2 on and off of feature1 using `git rebase feature1` and `git rebase --onto develop feature1`. I've rectified the situation by cherry-picking A, B and C on to a fresh branch off develop, but: how could this have come about? I'm stumped.

---

### Edit

I have *no idea* what Github is doing here, but now Git is saying:

```
Your branch and 'origin/feature2-fresh' have diverged,
and have 113 and 100 different commit(s) each, respectively.
```

So it seems it's Github's fault?

Comment: These can't be the exact same commits in the sense of them having the same contents and the same SHA-1. What do you mean by the same commits?

Comment: Same diff, different SHA-1. I have no idea where they came from. ```git log --graph``` seemed to think develop, whereas ```git branch --contains``` just thought they were on feature2.

Comment: The second error message is indicative of two different rebase (one local, one pushed over to GitHub by another collaborator): the SHA1 are different (even if the content might be similar). One of the two side (local or GitHub) will have to reset its content to the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what happened:

- So I rebased `feature2` onto `feature1`.
- I rebased `feature2` back onto `develop`.
- I pushed `feature2`, then realised there was more work to do, so did the rebase dance again (`feature1` was needed to run `feature2`).

Now the SHA-1s of all the commits unique to `feature2` are different to the corresponding commits on `origin/feature2`.
Without realising, I do a `pull`. Git dutifully merges all the commits again, because  they have different SHAs. The moral of the story is:

## Don't rebase a pushed branch.

Comment: Good feedback, more detailed than my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

One possibility:
Duplicate commit can be a telltale for `git cherry-pick` (see "[git - what is cherry-pick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13522664/git-what-is-cherry-pick/13524494#13524494)" and [its duplicate commit issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627953/git-cherry-pick-and-datamodel-integrity/2628915#2628915)).

If A and B were cherry-picked at any point after the rebase, they could be added to feature2 even though that branch already contains A and B (with different SHA1).

If A and B were cherry-picked *before* the rebase, then A and B should not have been repeated (from [`git rebase` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase))

> If the upstream branch already contains a change you have made (e.g., because you mailed a patch which was applied upstream), then that commit will be skipped.

Comment: @MattBrennan well, you can cherry-pick a range of commit ;) http://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309