# How Do I Implement Semantic Versioning in Git?

Tags: git, versioning

I've been able to convince my group to use [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) and move to git (from CVS, where all development happened on the trunk).

This is what we've been using for a bit (where the version branches denote the introduction of some kind of new functionality):

```
master
*
|
*   * version 2.0 branch
|  /
* *
|/
*   * version 1.0 branch
|  /
* *
|/
*
|
...
```

The problem is that when there's a bugfix that needs to be made on the version 1.0 branch, that fix needs to get echoed up to version 2.0 and master. We've been cherry-picking, but I feel like that's more error-prone than I'd like (and I feel like it'll become unmanageable as time goes on).

There are some limitations to what we're doing--it's legacy code, and there isn't a lot of testing being done (starting to introduce unit testing, very little integration testing), so keeping stability on those version branches (not introducing a lot of regression errors) is important.

Do you guys have a better way to approach this than cherry-picking? Is there a better workflow to use? Really appreciative of any help you can provide.

Comment: When do you branch out your release-branches? Is there a lot of development done on those release-branches?

Comment: How many release branches do you have simultaneously? I don’t think there should be a `1.x`, `2.x` *and* a general development branch around for semver. You should try to get previous major versions closed as soon as possible. I would actually go as far to say that you shouldn’t do any non-patch updates for any older version, so you would only have a single development branch and one for each still supported version.

Comment: Try reading [A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) to see if it helps :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Cherry-picking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13524494/6309) can:

- introduce [duplicate commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627953/git-cherry-pick-and-datamodel-integrity/2628915#2628915)
- miss [functional dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git/881112#881112)

I prefer **merging** (which is similar to [A successfull Git branching](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301174/how-do-i-implement-semantic-versioning-in-git#comment21603020_15301174) by [desert69](https://stackoverflow.com/users/641451/desert69)):

- create a branch dedicated to that `buxfix_xxx` (on top of version1)
- merge version1 to that `buxfix_xxx` branch (fast-forward)
- merge `buxfix_xxx` to `version 2` and `master` branches

Of course, the trick is to record a merge in those branches (version2 and master) without actually merging *all* the files: see "[How do you merge selective files with git-merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449541/how-do-you-merge-selective-files-with-git-merge)".

If you have only a few files to merge, here is what I do:

```
# make git believe we are merging everything
git checkout version2
git merge --no-commit bugfix_xxx

# but reset everything to version2
# (while the merge is still in progress!)
git checkout version2 -- .

# merge only the few files we need:
git checkout --patch bugfix_xxx -- path/to/file1
git checkout --patch bugfix_xxx -- path/to/file2
git checkout --patch bugfix_xxx -- path/to/file3

# add and commit, concluding the merge
```

The nice thing about those merges is that, the next one (from `version1` to `version2` and `master`) will naturally be limited to the next bugfix, because git will believe that *everything else* was *already merge*!

So the time you invest in that first backport of a bugfix will pay of for the next ones.

Comment: You forgot to add "back-|forwardporting may and will be separate task" - you can't merge changes for old code into new codebase (and in inverse direction also)

Comment: @LazyBadger so you wouldn't treat "back-|forwardporting" as merges, like I just did for bugfixes?

Comment: No, they **are** and **must be** merges, but they can be non-trivial merges (if context was changed between releases). I do not disagree with you, I only warn about (possible) troubles in porting changes into "non-native" branches