# Git - 2 separate develop branches - cherrypicking or not?

Tags: git, merge, branch, cherry-pick

I have 2 separate develop branches in Git, *develop1* and *develop2*.
These 2 branches have a common ancestor, commit *C1* on master. These 2 branches contain 2 product releasecycles will will be joined in about 6 months (both merged into master).

Before the big merge in 6 months, branches *develop1* and *develop2* will be kept separate, no merging between develop1 <-> develop2 will be done.

However, some changes (like project structure, script changes) will be done on both branches.

My idea is to perform these changes on *develop1*, then cherry-pick them to *develop2*.

My questions:

1. Is this wise to do?
2. Will this result in problems later when performing the big merge?

The reason I'm asking this is because I've read that cherry-picking may result in problems because new commits are created.

One reference listing the possible problem:
http://blog.founddrama.net/2013/07/git-cherry-pick/

Comment: IMO, whether you use cherry pick or manually add commits to d2, it is going to be a different commit, hence you would run into problems (if at all). I am hoping the anticipated conflicts should not be too hard to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ma always referring to the same issues with cherry-picking (as in "[git - cherry-pick - HOWTO / WHYTO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13524494/6309)")

- [duplicate commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627953/git-cherry-pick-and-datamodel-integrity/2628915#2628915)
- [functional dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git/881112#881112)

The second issue is not relevant here, as you are chrry-picking only commits that work on their own and are tested/validated on the second branch well before they are merged on master.

But the first one can be an issue when `develop1`, *then* `develop2` will be merged to *master*. The merge itself should be fine.
But, as explained in "[Git cherry pick and datamodel integrity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2628915/6309)", a change will appear twice in the history of a merged commit.

If possible, once `develop1` is merged to `master`, I would rebase `develop2` on top of an updated `origin/master`, before merging `develop2` back to `master`: that would detect identical commits and not apply them twice.