# How to merge one branch change to another?

Tags: git

I have two branches on my local, i.e. master and foo. I recently took a pull from origin and updated my master branch. Now I want to merge those changes into the branch foo and then commit and push those changes in that branch itself?

How to do I do that?

I can't seem to wrap my head around the merge command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
git checkout foo
git merge master
```

But that will merge *all* commits since `foo` started from `master` (or at least since `master` was last merged into `foo`: see [`git merge-base`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base))

```
              (new commits after git pull)
             vvvv
 x--x--x--x--X--X  (master, origin/master)
    \
     f--f--f       (foo)
```

Merges into

```
         (ALL those commits are merged in foo: x as well as X)
       vvvvvvvvvv
 x--x--x--x--X--X        (master, origin/master)
    \            \
     f--f--f -----M      (foo)
```

Comment: and what if I want to merge one particular commit of the master branch into my branch `foo`?

Comment: @JohnDui Then you can cherry-pick one or multiple commits from one branch to the other: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309

Comment: @JohnDui but beware of issues with cherry-picking mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/13524494/6309 (see the two links mentioned in that answer)