# How to get only changes from branch's branch in git?

Tags: eclipse, git, branch, egit

```
                   change 1, change 2, change 3, change 4
                  /
master >> Branch A
                  \ Branch A1
                             \
                              change 1001
```

I have made a branch A from the master at the beginning. Then I have made a branch out of branch (A1).

Over time I have make several changes to Branch A.
I have also done some changes to Branch A1.

Now I would like to get only Branch A1's change to master (change 1001), without the changes to Branch A (changes 1-4).

Can this be done easily with git? And if it's possible, what would be appropriate steps to achieve this?

I'm using eGit plugin in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
x--x--x (master)
       \
        y--y1--change 1, change 2, change 3, change 4 (branchA)
            \
             change 1001 (branchA1)
```

or:

```
         change 1001 (branchA1)
       /
x--x--x (master)
       \
        y--y--change 1, change 2, change 3, change 4 (branchA)
```

In the second case (`branchA1` comes from `master`), you could simply merge `branchA1` on `master`.

But in the first case (`branchA1` comes from `branchA`), you can:

```
git cherry-pick change 1001
```

But that would leave some [duplicate commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2628915/6309) and is subject to [functional dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/881112/6309).
I try to avoid cherry-picking, if possible.

Or:

```
git rebase --onto master y1 branchA1
```

That will *move* all commits from `branchA1` (after `y1` of `branchA`) onto `master` branch. No duplicate commits

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer.