# Git workflow to distribute changes to several branches

Tags: git

I have a Git repo with two massively diverged branches A and B:

- A is the upstream branch of the open source software
- B are all changes we made to it (from a very early commit from A as a starting point)

What we would like to have is

- A as above
- B having all the changes we want to make available to the upstream developers
- C with all the changes which only apply to our specific use of the software

So I find myself in the situation of having to split up the changes in B into two parts and commit them to different branches. What I did until now is to have two checkouts of the repository (B and C)

Is there a built-in git tool or a workflow that handles this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply create a `C` branch, and cherry-pick the relevant commits from `B` to `C`.

I generally avoid cherry-picking because it [duplicates commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2628915/6309) and can create [functional dependencies errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/881112/6309).

But in your case, if 'C' isn't merged back to any other branch, it is a good solution.

Comment: Thanks, thats a start. The problem is that it does only work if a set of changes from one commit does never have to be split up into different commits. Unfortunately, this is the case a lot. Do you have an idea to solve also that?