# How to merge one change from an old branch to a new branch?

Tags: git

The scenario:

- dev in the master branch
- fork master into a Feature branch, and send it to QA, with one Feature in it
- dev some more in master
- `git checkout Feature`
- make one little fix
- send Feature, with that fix, back to QA
- `git checkout master`
- `git merge Feature`

Imagine my surprise when Git said "okay, you want master to look like Fix now", and threw away all of my "dev some more" changes. I need it to only apply the only hashtag that differed from when the two branches forked.

How do I perform this simple & obvious scenario? The nightmare would be me making the same change in master, then getting an irrelevant irreconcilable merge conflict when the same change goes into a "production" branch...

Comment: Odd that this is happening. It should work as you expect.

Answer (score 5):

If nobody depends on your feature branch (ie if nobody has pulled from hat branch that you have pushed), I would, to be sure, rebase it on top of `master`:

```
git checkout master
# make sure master is up-todate
git pull

# rebase my feature branch on top of master
git checkout myFeatureBranch
git rebase origin/master
```

That replays your modifications on top of master, and you can resolve any conflict locally within your feature branch.

Then the merge back to master is a trivial fast-forward one

```
git checkout master
git merge myFeatureBranch
```

Finally you can push `master`: the upstream repo will accept those changes again as a fast-forward merge (you are only adding new commits on top of `origin/master`)

Comment: Unfortunately for our thread, git cherry-pick worked. In this case, there was only one hashtag to pick. I suppose I could have cherry-picked a list of them. But I also thought (from twitter) that rebase was evil, so this answer must go unconfirmed. Tx all!

Comment: @Phlip I don't trust cherry-picking unless it is a one-time operation (meaning you will leave that branch from which you are cherry-picking behind and not use it anymore). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18445186/6309

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 possibility :
1/ You should first merge your master changes on your Feature, resolve your conflict potentially, then when it's ok, merge your Feature in the master.

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout Feature 
git pull 
git merge master --no-commit --no-ff

# Analyze the changes that will be merged into your Feature
git commit 
git push
```

and do the same merge on your master

2/ Cherry pick the commits you want, update conflict and commit.

```
git cherry-pick _your_Hash_
```

Comment: Your first suggestion looks like I want to put all of the HEAD of master into Feature; I want to leave Feature alone. I will try your second suggestion.