# Git merge vs cherry-pick for two differing branches

Tags: git, merge

I'm having two branches without a common ancestor, let's call them `master` and `other`. Their content differs a lot and this has to stay. New changes are nearly always done on `master` and cherry-picked to `other` with some manual merging, which can't be eliminated. This won't change either.

I wonder what are the consequences of fake-merging `master` into `other` like this

```
git checkout other
git merge -s ours master
```

and then always merging instead of cherry-picking. The advantages are clear:

- it obviates the need to remember what to cherry-pick
- it allows to merge multiple changes at once (which may be sometimes easier)
- it establishes a clear relationship between the branches

I can imagine that it makes my life a bit harder in the rare cases when something doesn't need to be picked into the other branch, but this is no real problem. Before I do it, I'd like to know if there are any disadvantages I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No obvious disadvantages, especially when compared to the ones of cherry-picking, namely;

- [duplicate commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2628915/6309)
- [functional dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/881112/6309)

So fake merging allows you to reset the merge common ancestor to a more recent commit, and from there merge only what you needs.

Note there are solution for [merging all files except one or two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1355990/6309):

```
git reset <paths>...
git add -p <paths>...
```

Comment: Sounds good and you seem to know what you're saying. The question is why I didn't come to this idea earlier? I've never seen anyone recommending this fake-merge.

Comment: @maaartinus because most of the time, it involves only reporting a few commits over to a branch, not "all commits except a file or two". In the formar case, cherry-picking is the usual solution.