# Pushing selected changes to production

Tags: git, deployment, version-control

I am using Git/Heroku for a work application. Usually, changes will be merged into master then pushed to staging then production. But now I need to push only selected changes (patches) to production. How should I do that?

1. Some initial state in master
2. Patch 1
3. Patch 2
4. Patch 3
5. Patch 4
6. Patch 5

My first thought was to pull from heroku/production. Copy changes here (eg. a subset possibly from patch 2 and 4) and then only push into heroku production. I think this will work, in the short term. But in the future how do I manage such "divergent" changes? Since now master and production is different. When I push from master into production, I guess I will get conflicts? Either that or I will end up overriding changes made on production? How are such changes managed?

Answer (score 0):

> But in the future how do I manage such "divergent" changes?

By creating a dedicated branch "`prod`" from which you [cherry-pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) the right commits you want from master (instead of a global merge)

> Since now master and production is different. When I push from master into production, I guess I will get conflicts?

Yes: once you start cherry-picking commits, you shouldn't merge anymore.
(because of [duplicate commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627953/git-cherry-pick-and-datamodel-integrity/2628915#2628915) and [functional dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git/881112#881112))

The best reconciliation between those two branches is make `master` stable enough for it to *replace* the the `prod` branch (meaning you reset `prod` to `master`)

I do precisely that "double-branch" approach in my [compileEverything project](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/branches).

[image: master and prod]