# "Cherry-pick" in Github App for Mac

Tags: git, github

I have one commit on my `Staging` branch I'd like to push over to my `master` branch. I am using the Github app for Mac and I don't see a way to do this.

I know how to do this in Terminal.

Learning how to `cherry-pick` in the Github app would be nice as I enjoy using it too.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do it from the terminal - the GUI app is great for easy stuff. Anything more complex than basic commit/push/pull/merge not so much.

Comment: Removed irrelevant tags.

Comment: @max I agree with you but maybe we can find information for how to do this from GitHub desktop.  This is the actual question.

Comment: [This documentation](https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/contributing/) mentions basic Git operations, but does not mention cherry pick.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. I contacted Github Support so I'll post an update when I hear back.

Comment: Ok. Github returned my message. Here it is: "Cherry Picking is not currently available for the Desktop version of Github. However, it is on a list of features we intend to implement so expect it soon!"

Answer (score 6):

If you want a GUI app to do more advanced commands like cherry-pick, i suggest a free alternative to the official Github app: [Sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) ([preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gue7H.png)).

It could take months/years before the official Github app supports advanced commands. (I emailed them about another feature several months ago, and it has yet to be implemented)

Comment: Just started using Sourcetree and I love it! I'm not sure if I should mark this as the answer or not but thanks for the recommendation. Great alternative!

Comment: Thanks also for the recommend. I also had to do cherry-pick via GUI and SourceTree is just right.

Answer (score 2):

> Learning how to cherry-pick in the Github app would be nice as I enjoy using it too.
>
> Any suggestions?

A 2021 suggestion: update GitHub Desktop, as it does now (March 2021, 5 years later) have cherry-picking!

> ### [GitHub Desktop now supports cherry-picking](https://github.blog/2021-03-30-github-desktop-now-supports-cherry-picking/) (GitHub Desktop 2.7)

> Cherry-picking is a handy feature for when you would like to copy commits from one branch to another.
> What more intuitive way to copy a commit than by simply picking it up, dragging it to your branch, and dropping it there!
>
> For example, you start working on a new feature, and several commits into development you identify an existing bug in the underlying architecture.
> You create a couple of commits to fix that bug.
> Then, you decide that the fix needs to go into production and can’t wait until this feature is finished.
> No problem! Just create a release branch and use GitHub Desktop to cherry-pick those commits to your new branch for the hotfix.
>
> #### Drag and dropping commits
>
> Want to cherry-pick a single commit? Just start dragging it.
>
> What about multiple commits? Shift+click the range you would like to copy, and drag away.
>
> [image: Cherry-picking features -- https://github.blog/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/multiple-commits.gif]
>
> There are several goodies that come with cherry-picking:
>
> **Undo**: You cherry-picked a group of commits and immediately realized that you cherry-picked one too many.
> That’s not a problem. Just click undo in the success banner to remove those commits, and it puts you back on the branch you started from.
>
> - **Conflict resolution**: Not all cherry-picks are this easy, and conflicts may arise. The same conflict resolution dialog you’re familiar with from merging and rebasing is available for taking care of merge conflicts.
> - **Context menu**: Not a fan of drag and drop? Just right click on a commit or set of commits, and select the cherry-pick option to open a branch dialog to select your target branch.

As usual with cherry-picking, beware of:

- [commit duplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627953/git-cherry-pick-and-datamodel-integrity/2628915#2628915)
- [missed functional dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git/881112#881112)