# git flow vs cherry-picks

Tags: git, workflow

We have branches **`prod`** for production releases and **`dev`** for ongoing development.

### Our current flow:

We work mainly in **`dev`** branch and from time to time, customer decides which features/bugfixes he wants to come to **`prod`** and we cherry-pick them.

From my understanding, cherry-picks contradict to **`git flow`** model.

And so far I don't see how to adapt our flow to avoid it.
**`git flow`** assumes that you know beforehand should the change go to **`prod`** or not

Does community see any way around it?

## UPDATE: I found that my question requires a better clarification of terms

### What we use now

#### To implement a issue #12345

```
git fetch
git checkout origin/dev -B issue-12345 # new branch for issue #12345 from bug tracking system
# ... do many atomic commits
git fetch
git checkout origin/dev -B dev
git merge issue-12345 --no-ff -m "Bug #12345 - Bug title from bug tracking system"
# ... fix merge conflicts if any and commit
git branch -D issue-12345
git push
```

NOTES

1. We use atomic commits for each commit to have a clear intent. This simplifies review/blame/bisect processes
2. We use custom message for merge as it is way more descriptive than default `Merge 'issue-12345' into 'dev'`
3. We force non-fast-forward merges via `--no-ff` because we want all issue to be represented as a merge. So `git log dev --first-parent` returns high-level view of the tasks completed
4. We don't use `git merge --squash` and its rebase analogues. We want whole task history to be preserved

#### When client decides that he wants to get issue #12345 into production

```
git fetch
git checkout origin/prod -B issue-12345
git log origin/dev --grep "#12345" --oneline --reverse # get all commits that have to be cherry-picked, usually that's only one merge commit (abcd1234)
git cherry-pick abcd1234 -x -m 1 # '-m 1' required for cherry-picking merge commit
# ... fix merge conflicts if any and commit
# ... repeat for other commit if any
git checkout origin/prod -B prod
git merge issue-12345-prod --no-ff -m "Bug #12345 - Bug title from bug tracking system"
# ... fix merge conflicts if any and commit (although that's unlikely for them to occur)
git branch -D issue-12345
git push
```

### What `git flow` told us to do

See http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ for more details

In terms of that article our `dev` branch corresponds to `develop`, `prod` corresponds to `master`, release branches are not used

According to `git flow`, only feature branches should be based on `dev` branch, and they are never merged to `prod`.

However hotfix branches should be based on `prod` and then merged to both `prod` and `dev`.

### Why `git flow` is not applicable for us

1. We don't know beforehand if the task will need to go to `prod` branch or not.
2. If we base feature branch from `dev`, we won't be able to merge it to `prod` later on if that will be requested (possibly much-much later)
3. If we base feature branch from `prod`, we won't be able to benefit from other tasks completed before.

#### Example 1

Let's say we have a task #12345 to implement a new `Contact Us` page. And then we have a task #23456 to change the page's background color from white to yellow.

We based our `issue-12345` branch from `prod` and then merged it into `dev` and waiting for approval to merge it into `prod`.

Then we start working on `issue-23456` and based on `prod` again. But `prod` code doesn't even have any mentions of `Contact Us` page yet. So we'll have to do some quirks such as merging `issue-12345` branch into `issue-23456` first.

That's complicated enough for even that simple case. And you can imagine it will be much more difficult if you want to use some code introduced in other task.

#### Example 2

Task #34567 asks to implement `Feedback` page. This page is very similar to `Contact Us` page so it has similar css. We would like to reuse it. But how? It's not fair to say that #34567 depends on #12345. So it would be illogical to base `issue-34567` on `issue-12345`. So what? Rewrite code manually? Copy-paste? Or still cherry-picks?

I don't see any reasonable solution for such issue.

Comment: Your current flow seems to work for you - why do you want to change it?

Comment: One of the major reasons, is the fact that `prod` and `dev` become too diverged so cherry-picking becomes too painful

Answer (score 6):

git-flow (seen [here translated as regular git commands](https://gist.github.com/JamesMGreene/cdd0ac49f90c987e45ac)) is based on merging branches (features into dev, dev into master)

`git cherry-pick` is not compatible with merge because of:

- [duplicating commits on merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2628915/6309),
- [functional dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/881112/6309)

So if your current workflow based on cherry-picking works, you ought to keep it.
However, as explained in "[If you cherry pick, your branch model is wrong](http://www.draconianoverlord.com/2013/09/07/no-cherry-picking.html)":

> Their insight is that, with git (or any DAG-based SCM), if you can anticipate where a commit may/will be need to applied, you can put it on it’s own branch, and merge it into those various places as needed.
>
> This will get the change applied to all the necessary branches (you can merge it into release as well as master), but not result in the commit getting copy/pasted. Instead, new merge commits will be recorded, so no new commit ids, and the history (what branches have this commit?) is tracked nicely in the DAG.

Yet:

> The con to not cherry picking is that you’ll need to know up front that you want your commit applied into multiple places, so that you can place it on it’s own branch.

In your case, that would involve multiple separate feature branches, merged into master only after approval by the client.

---

Regarding git-flow, it is true  it is not a good fit for you. An integration model is more accurate:

It is simpler to have an **`integration`** branch which starts from `master` and with:

- features branches created from the `integration` branch
- those same feature branches *rebased* on top of the updated `integration` branch each time other features have been merged to `integration`: that involve communicating with the team in charge of that feature branch as they will have to reset their own copy of the feature branch each time it is rebased (since its history would change)
- the merge commit from a feature, result of the merge of a feature branch to `integration`, [can be reverted at any time if that feature is dropped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6217372/6309): all other feature branches not yet merged need to rebase themselves on top of the updated `integration` branch.

Once the `integration` branch is feature complete and has passed user acceptance tests, it would be merged to `master` (or `prod`)

---

From the OP's scenario, when features can go individually into prod at any time, you don't need `dev` or `integration`:

> Day 1. `prod`=`dev`=`integration`

Let's consider only `prod` and `integration` here, and feature or issue branches.

> Day 2. Issue #1 raised. Here it is obvious. All branches are the same. So we can `git checkout prod -B issue-1`
>
> Day 3. Issue #1 fixed. Do we merge `issue-1` branch anywhere?

Merge --no-ff to `integration`

> Day 4. Issue #2 raised. Basing from integration branch again?

Here based on `prod`. Especially if it is an issue (detected in `prod`).
If it is a feature, you can consider starting it from `integration`, but since features will be dropped from `integration`, the benefit of an early integration won't be a guaranty.

> Day 5. Issue #2 fixed. Merging anywhere?

To `integration` (`merge --no-ff`), to check if issue 2 works with issue 1.

> Day 6. Issue #2 approved to get into prod. What do we do?

First, rebase `issue-2` on top of `prod` (in case of prod have evolved since then)
Then `merge --no-ff issue-2` to `prod`.

Reset `integration` to `prod`, and merge all the other features branches back into `integration`, in order to validate if they play well together on top of the new prod (which now includes `issue-2`).

> Day 7. Issue #1 approved to get into prod. What do we do?

First, rebase `issue-1` on top of `prod`: that will validate that `issue-1` is still working, even when based on top of `issue-2` (which was merged into `prod` previously).
Then, merge --no--ff.

Note the use of `merge --no-ff`, which generates a merge commit in `prod` or `integration` from a feature/issue branch: if said feature/issue needs to be dropped from `prod`, all you need to do is to revert that unique merge commit in `prod` or `integration` (instead of reverting a series of commits representing the branch to drop).

Comment: that's not an option unfortunately, as an "approval" may take a significant amount of time

Comment: @mnaoumov an "aproval" would not take any more time than your current approval leading you to cherry-pick commits.

Comment: sorry maybe I misunderstood your point. Do you mean to base all feature branches from `prod` branch and merge them in once requested?

Comment: @mnaoumov if you are using git-flow, feature branches are not based on prod, but on develop (https://gist.github.com/JamesMGreene/cdd0ac49f90c987e45ac#create-a-feature-branch). But the more general point is that, if you can isolate a feature in its own branch, then the need to cherry-pick from a common branch goes away.

Comment: @mna I just saw your edit. I am not at home right now. I will check that out when I return.

Comment: @mnaoumov I am back home, and I have updated the answer with an integration -based workflow which you might find more accurate, *and* which does not involve any cherry-picking. That model does respect the fact you do not know in advance the features which will be part of the next release.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer but unfortunately I don't get it fully. Can you provide some example involving `prod`, `dev` and `integration` branches?

Like

Day 1. `prod`=`dev`=`integration`
Day 2. Issue #1 raised. Here it is obvious. All braches are the same. So we can `git checkout integration -B issue-1`
Day 3. Issue #1 fixed. Do we merge `issue-1` branch anywhere?
Day 4. Issue #2 raised. Basing from `integration` branch again?
Day 5. Issue #2 fixed. Merging anywhere?
Day 6. Issue #2 approved to get into `prod`. What do we do?
Day 7. Issue #1 approved to get into `prod`. What do we do?

Comment: @mnaoumov I didn't get that features could go individually into prod (instead of being integrated over a period of time, *and then* going into prod. I have updated my answer to address your specific scenario.

Comment: Sorry but your last scenario doesn't have much sense. Feature approvals may take a significant time. But those resolved issues are still have to be tested on time. So at least one extra branch (such as `dev`) is needed to get finished issues as soon as they are ready

Comment: @mnaoumov ok, I have added back the `integration` branch into your scenario in order to allow testing in advanced of the feature/issue branches currently selected to be part of the next prod release.

Comment: Thanks that's clear now. However your idea has the same flaws I described in the update to the original question in Examples section. And secondly we have dozens of issues. It will be very time consuming to rebase and merge all of them all the time. Cherry-picking looks much better in this light

Comment: @mnaoumov the all point is to avoid cherry-picking, for reasons I lay out at the beginning of the answer. Rebasing and merging should *not* be time consuming. Rebasing and merging is what git does best.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to point out that we had a similar issue with our workflow and opted for a "revert" workflow instead of cherry-picking. When creating a release which can contain one or more features we find the latest feature in develop branch that we want to go into the release and then branch from there. We then decide which feature merges (git log --first-parent) we don't want to go in from under that and revert them. Once the release is done we "un-revert" by reverting the revert and merging back to the develop branch.

Though git cherry and some other commands show the "un-revert" commit as the one that made the code changes, git blame is smart enough to actually follow the history back to the origin feature commit and there is also a trail of commit messages with ids.

Answer (score 1):

Working with `cherry-pick` is a very decent way to do it.

#### But

The **"problem**" is that git flow merge you branches into each other (fully and then delete them as part of its flow) so using `cherry-pick` along with `git-flow` is some sort of **abusing** git flow.

---

#### How do deliver features to customer?

In my opinion you should consider developing feature toggle mechanism for choosing which features to turn/off per customer.

Comment: yeah, feature toggles would solve such issues, but this is a bit orthogonal to git flow. If feature toggles are implemented properly, the only difference between `dev` and `prod` branch - is a feature settings file