# Can I cherry-pick back into git master/maser from a branch?

Tags: git, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

On git I have two branches, Items and Master both of which are several commits ahead of the local master/maser which is in sync with the remove master/master. I want to cherry-pick my branch master F and add it to the local master/master B ready to be committed to the remote master/master. (I believe I understand cherry-pick.)

Do I have to start a new branch to cherry-pick to and then have to rebase the two branches or is there a better way to make this change?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a master branch whose B is an ancestor, you don't have to cherry-pick anything: you can directly push it to origin.

The problem with [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) is that you are:

- [duplicating commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2628915/6309),
- and [ignoring functional dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/881112/6309)

In your case, a `rebase --onto` is preferable:

```
git checkout master
git rebase --onto B E mster
```

With:

- `B`: your "master/master": Replace `B` by the name of the branch referencing `B` (`origin/master`, maybe?)
- `E`: the last commit before the `F` commits
- `master`: the most recent commit of `F`

The OP adds: In the end I actually used `git rebase -i HEAD~14` which gave me the ability to see what I was doing. Thanks

Comment: However, I do not want to push the intervening commits and I do not know any other method.

Comment: @Frank Do you mean you need to push only F, not E?

Comment: Yes, E is actually about 10 commits and the work is not yet complete. F stands alone cleanly and should just work as it does not affect the intervening commits.

Comment: @Frank OK. A `rebase --onto` is in order then. See my edited answer.