# How to port the change of one branch to another branch

Tags: git

I have a change which has been committed and pushed to the remote of `dev-branch` and now I want to push this change also to the `mainline`.

The approach I could think of is that duplicate the changes in the local and then commit/push to the `mainline`, but this looks like would make a single change becomes irrelevant commits across `dev-branch` and `mainline`?

So what is the correct way to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: There is no such thing as committing a “change”. A commit is a snapshot of everything, at the time. It’s unclear what you wish to do or why it’s hard.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single commit that you want to report/replicate from one branch to another, the correct command is [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) (which can also be [applied to a range of commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309))

That might make a future merge between branches slightly harder, because of [duplicate commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2628915/6309)

Answer (score -1):

Isn't this what merge is for?

```sh
git checkout mainline
git pull origin mainline  # this should fast-forward
git merge dev-branch
git push origin mainline
```

EDIT: also could use a pull request for the same effect

Comment: No: merge would report the change *and all the other changes* of one branch to another. If the change is limited to a commit, `git cherry-pick` is the correct command.

Comment: Yeah I guess I misunterstood the use case