# How do I merge a specific commit from one branch into another in Git?

Tags: git, github

I have `BranchA` which is 113 commits ahead of `BranchB`.

But I only want the last 10 or so commits from `BranchA` merged into `BranchB`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to merge a specific commit in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git)

Answer (score 358, accepted):

The `git cherry-pick <commit>` command allows you to take a single commit (from whatever branch) and, essentially, rebase it in your working branch.

[Chapter 5 of the Pro Git book explains it better than I can](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Maintaining-a-Project#_rebase_cherry_pick), complete with diagrams and such. ([The chapter on Rebasing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing) is also good reading.)

Lastly, there are some [good comments on the cherry-picking vs merging vs rebasing in another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241720/git-cherry-pick-vs-merge-workflow).

Comment: Question: say commit `A` is branched off of `master` and you do some work on it, creating child commits `B` through `E`. Say `E` only has 1 line added from `D`. If you `git cherry-pick E` into `master`, does it apply *all* the changes from `A` through `E` into the `master` branch, or does it *only* apply the change from `D` to `E`, namely, it adds only that 1 line to `master`? If the case is the former, how do I achieve the latter? (aside from manually copying and pasting)

Comment: git cherry-pick -n <commit> If you don't want the cherry pick auto-committed.

Comment: little side-note: you can manually do it on github desktop (right click on specific commit to cherry pick) -- then it's intuitive :)

Answer (score 10):

If BranchA has not been pushed to a remote then you can reorder the commits using `rebase` and then simply `merge`. It's preferable to use `merge` over `rebase` when possible because it doesn't create duplicate commits.

```
git checkout BranchA
git rebase -i HEAD~113
... reorder the commits so the 10 you want are first ...
git checkout BranchB
git merge [the 10th commit]
```