# single commit from one branch onto another

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I merge a specific commit from one branch into another in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372044/how-do-i-merge-a-specific-commit-from-one-branch-into-another-in-git)

I'm newby to git. Got a question: If I want a single commit from one branch onto another branch, what command should I use? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like: 
`git cherry-pick 575f9b1a75673067830bb224ee09b201923093a6`

or

`git cherry-pick my-branch` (to get the top commit on my-branch).

Answer (score 3):

Use cherry pick, as per:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html