# How can i merge a git commit from a different branch?

Tags: git, merge, branch, commit

Collaborating with a dev, i want to merge a selected commit from his branch into mine and push it to production.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6372044/6754053

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I merge a specific commit from one branch into another in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372044/how-do-i-merge-a-specific-commit-from-one-branch-into-another-in-git)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use git cherry pick

- First go the the branch where you can to merge the commit (here your own branch)
- Now copy the SHA id of the dev's commit
- `git cherry-pick sha-id`