# Pull/merge a specific range of commits of a branch

Tags: git

This sounds like a basic problem, but I can't seem to find a similar question. Maybe I am searching with wrong keywords... Please point me to duplicates if any.

I have 2 branches in my remote reposiroty `mybranchX`, `mybranchY`.

Both the branches have a set of separate commits like

```
mybranchX : commitXA--commitXB--commitXC--commitXD--commitXE--HEAD

mybranchY : commitYP--commitYQ--commitYR--commitYS--HEAD
```

I want to pull `commitXC` and earlier into `mybranchY`

How to do this?

**P.S.** I know `git cherry-pick commitXC` will pick the code changes of the particular commit. But I want the entire history till `commitXC` :

```
commitXA--commitXB--commitXC
```

and none after that, i.e. I dont want `commitXD--commitXE`

Needless to say, the actual number of commits in my case is large(quite a few dozens), and cherry picking each and every commit is going to be a long task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I merge a specific commit from one branch into another in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372044/how-do-i-merge-a-specific-commit-from-one-branch-into-another-in-git)

Comment: Why can't you just `git checkout mybranchX`, `git merge mybranchY`?

Comment: Because I don't want commitXD--commitXE, but i want commitYR--commitYS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular case, you just need `git merge`.

Let's redraw your graph.  Instead of:

```
mybranchX : commitXA--commitXB--commitXC--commitXD--commitXE--HEAD

mybranchY : commitYP--commitYQ--commitYR--commitYS--HEAD
```

let's use

```
       A--B--C--D--E   <-- mybranchX
      /
...--*   [this commit and all earlier commits are on BOTH branches]
      \
       P--Q--R--S   <-- mybranchY (HEAD)
```

as this is (presumably) an accurate representation of the state of the repository and your current branch after you run `git checkout mybranchY`, which attaches the name `HEAD` to `mybranchY`.

(To verify this, compare this horizontal graph drawing with Git's own vertically-oriented drawing as output by `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`.  Note that it is important here that the commit I marked `*` be the actual merge base, i.e., the point where the two branches split apart.)

Since your `HEAD` denotes commit `S` and you wish to merge with all commits up to and including commit `C`, find a name that identifies commit `C`, such as its raw hash ID or the string `mybranchX~2`.  The `~2` suffix tells Git to count backwards (leftwards, in this drawing) two commits (following the first parent links, but these commits have only a first parent).  Since `mybranchX` names commit `E`, if we count back twice, we get to commit `C`.

Then simply run:

```
git merge mybranchX~2  # or git merge <hash-id>
```

which will start the merge process.  Git will compare commit `*`, the merge base, to commit `C` to see what they did.  It will compare commit `*` to commit `S` to see what you did:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-*> HEAD        # what we did: --ours
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-*> <hash-of-C> # what they did: --theirs
```

Git will now combine these two diffs, applying the changes to commit `*`.  If all goes well, it will make a new *merge commit* automatically.  The two parents of the new merge commit—I will call it `T` here—will be commit `S` (as its first parent) and commit `C` (as its second):

```
       A---B---C--D--E   <-- mybranchX
      /         \
...--*           \
      \           \
       P--Q--R--S--T   <-- mybranchY (HEAD)
```

Hence `T~1` is `S`, `T~2` is `R`, and so on.  You can now name commit `C` by either `mybranchX~2` (count back two first-parent links) or by `mybranchY^2` (take the second parent of commit `T`).  Commits `A`, `B`, and `C` are now on `mybranchY` as well as still being on `mybranchX`.  Commits `D` and `E` are only on `mybranchX`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you are using the right terms. `pull` is syncing with remote repo and merge the changes.

I believe `cherry-pick` is what you looking for

```
git checkout mybranchY 
git cherry-pick commitXC
```

**Update**
To take all the  changes `commitXA--commitXB--commitXC` you can merge them

```
git checkout mybranchY 
git merge commitXC
```

Comment: But wont cherry-pick pick changes only from the commit commitXC? I want the entire history till commitXC i.e. commitXA--commitXB--commitXC

Comment: So use `merge` instead of `cherry-pick`