# Automatically rebase gerrit Changes

Tags: git, jenkins, rebase, gerrit

My current development environment consists of a Git/Gerrit setup which runs several Jenkins jobs to validate the submitted changes.

The submit type in Gerrit is set to "Fast-Forward only".

The "problem":

1. ***Change A*** is pushed to gerrit, validation builds on Jenkins are triggered
2. ***Change B*** is pushed to gerrit, validation builds on Jenkins are triggered
3. ***Change A*** gets "Verified +1" (from Jenkins)
4. ***Change B*** gets "Verified +1" (from Jenkins)
5. ***Change A*** is submitted

(Info: ***Change A/B*** are commits on the same branch and have the same parent commit-ID)

At this point in time ***Change B*** cannot be submitted anymore, because its parent does not point to the HEAD of the branch. So the developer of ***Change B*** has to manually rebase his change. (This rebase creates a new patchset, which automatically triggers the Jenkins jobs)

How can I get rid of this manual step?

So I found out that I can change the submit type of the Gerrit project to "Rebase if Necessary" (I can also tell Gerrit to automatically solve conflicts). The problem here is, that after rebasing and solving potential conflicts, the change is merged without re-running the Jenkins validation jobs. Potential bugs, which may have been introduced due to the rebase or the conflict solving, cannot be detected.

Is there a way to automatically rebase a change (in the Example ***Change B***) and re-run tests, when it is out-dated?

Comment: why did you checked _automatically resolve conflicts_ without it every path conflict should be rebased manually which will create new patchset - which generates the desired jenkins jobs

Comment: good point, I think I will disable the auto resolve, but the manual step would still be part of the workflow...

Comment: that is the point - conflict resolving should be reviewed by someone as well, not just code modifications. So just dont want to skip this step - maybe the tests passes but it is good to review with eyes as well - think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible out of the box, but you could write a service that listens to events (e.g. via the [stream-events SSH command](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-stream-events.html)) and rebases open changes destined for a particular branch when a change has been submitted to the same branch. It should be reasonably easy to write a plugin for this too, but that obviously also creates a tighter coupling.

Comment: hmmm... that's actually not what I wanted to hear. I thought that this problem should be a quite common one and that I didn't have to write custom triggers.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it can be done if you use the cherry pick feature.  See this other answer:
[Gerrit always rebase before submit patchset to avoid a merge commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633878/gerrit-always-rebase-before-submit-patchset-to-avoid-a-merge-commit)