# what git function allows me to approve/deny each change a commit will make?

Tags: git, commit

what `git` function allows me to approve/deny each change a commit will make?

I remember seeing this when I first started *gitting*, but can't seem to find it now...

I know I've done it once, where it gave a list of single letters, and each letter was a different aprove/deny/skip function. Does anyone know what I am talking about?

Comment: I guess you mean cherry picking: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241720/git-cherry-pick-vs-merge-workflow

Comment: I don't think there is such a function. When doing normal commits, you can selectively specify hunks to commit though.

Comment: Yes! how do i selectively specify hunks to commit?

Comment: Not tested, but you can start with `git merge --no-commit`, then you ought to be able to use combinations of `git add -p`, `git reset`, `git checkout`, etc. to accomplish what you want. I don't think there's a "simple" or "one command" way to do it, though.

Comment: @twalberg Thanks! i think it was `git add -p` that I was looking for and will test this out when I get home. If that's the case, then sorry for the incorrect title :) Although, I'm definitely still interested in finding out how to go change-by-change through a merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but you can start with `git merge --no-commit`, then you ought to be able to use combinations of `git add -p`, `git reset`, `git checkout`, etc. to accomplish what you want. I don't think there's a "simple" or "one command" way to do it, though.

Answer (score 4):

You're describing "git add -p".

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at "git rebase -i" 
and then "git rebase --continue"

I believe that this is what you are looking for.
But remember this work at commits level (not single lines).

Answer (score 1):

You are describing the "interactive mode" `git add -i`.

Something like [this](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/01/14/interactive-adding.html):

```
         staged     unstaged path
1:    unchanged        +3/-1 README.md
2:    unchanged        +1/-1 _layouts/default.html

*** Commands ***
1: status   2: update  3: revert  4: add untracked
5: patch    6: diff    7: quit    8: help
What now>
```