# git merge --no-commit vs git cherry-pick --no-commit

Tags: git, git-merge, git-cherry-pick

Is there any difference between `git merge --no-commit` and `git cherry-pick --no-commit`?

And is there any difference in history if I commit after these two commands?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you commit after `git merge --no-commit`, you'll actually get a merge commit. Whereas after a `git cherry-pick --no-commit` you'll get a commit with a single parent.

Hence, yes, there is a difference between those two commands.

In particular if you have something like

```
A -- B -- C
 \        L HEAD
  \
   -- D -- E
```

If you `cherry-pick` commit `E`, you won't get modifications of commit `D`. Whereas if you `merge`, you'll get both.

Answer (score 10):

While [git-merge](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) is used to join two or more development histories together, [git-cherry-pick](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) is used to apply changes introduced by some existing commits.

So then, once you commit after performing a [git-merge](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html), Git will add what's called a [merge commit](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging). In the other side, when [cherry-pick(ing)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) commits, git will apply the changes introduced by these commits on the top of your working tree (There's no fusion between two or many branches). Put another way, Commits are cloned and put on top of your branch.

Take a look at [Git Cherry-pick vs Merge Workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241720/git-cherry-pick-vs-merge-workflow) to undestand the differences based on a repo maintainer real needs.