# Get commits made in one branch to a different branch

Tags: git

I have committed some changes in one branch. Now I have to make the same changes in another branch.

Is there a way to get the previous commits to the current branch, so I can directly raise the pull request?

Comment: Try reading about `cherry-pick`

Comment: Tim is right; you're probably looking for `git cherry-pick`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241720/git-cherry-pick-vs-merge-workflow

Comment: If I know commit ID, How can I use cherry pick here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does cherry-picking a commit with git mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339429/what-does-cherry-picking-a-commit-with-git-mean)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the branch you want to have the commits in.  Then merge the branch that has the commits:
`git checkout master`

`git merge fixes`

I would give this a read. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

If you want to just apply selective commits, you should look into the `git cherry-pick` command. (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)