# In gitflow if we have a release branch open for one week can we still merge feature branches into develop

Tags: git, release-management, git-flow

In gitflow if we have a release branch open for one week can we still merge feature branches into develop.

We have a release branch open for a while because we do the cut off from develop and we keep the release branch open for one week. But at the same time we need to merge things back to develop. Is that correct? or we should do it in another branch temporally or release branch should not be open for so long? any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you create a release branch from develop, everything that gets committed or merged to develop is basically for the next release.

Imagine your current release is `1.0` (so `master` is on `1.0`) and you have finished implementing features for `1.1` in `develop`. You then branch `release` off of `develop` an increase the version number there to `1.1`. From this time on all changes that go to `develop` are for version `1.2`. If you need to fix stuff for release `1.1`, do it on the release branch. However, it should be only small, polishing changes ideally.
If you fear that these changes may  interfere too much with the parallel development for `1.2` that simultaneously takes place on `develop`, you may also introduce these changes also in develop and any feature branch that is still being developed on. Depending on the changes you can do so by either merging `release` to `develop` or by `cherry-pick`ing individual commits. You may want to read [how to merge a specific commit in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/881112/1557062) and also the differences in [Git Cherry-pick vs Merge Workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241720/git-cherry-pick-vs-merge-workflow).

Personally I don't see any problem with merging the version number change from `release` to `develop` before all work on `release` is finished. I would just make sure that my merge comment clearly tells that this is not the final merge but some intermediate one.

At the end one should keep in mind that git flow is only a measure to help developers organize their work. One should not make it a daily struggle to follow it strictly if in the end it does not fit the teams internal workflow.

Also see [Vincent Driessen's blog post that introduced git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/#release-branches) and a (slightly opinionated) [comparison of different branching models by Atlassian](https://de.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows).

[image]

Comment: but if I increase the version on release branch and merge a fix from release branch back to master then the version number that I have increesed in the code will be merged also to the develop branch and we don't want that right? we want the version to change on the release finish process...