# How do I manage externally maintained patches on software with git?

Tags: git, openssh

I'm trying to incorporate a community maintained patch on OpenSSH ([Roumen Petrov's X.509v3 implementation](http://roumenpetrov.info/openssh/)) along with our own patches. This does not fit regular solutions as far as I know, as this patch is huge and all releases of this patch are very much bound to a specific upstream version of OpenSSH. The obvious upgrade of OpenSSH on top of the patched version is a plain merge conflict and exactly what I want to avoid, yet keeping the upstream and patched version distinct in Git.

Right now, I have done this in Git using branches:

```
master
gert/develop
vendor/orig
vendor/roumenpetrov
```

With

- `vendor/orig` being a plain, original OpenSSH branch of code with every commit one of the OpenSSH release versions, also tagged, e.g. `5.9p1`
- `vendor/roumenpetrov` being a branch forked from `vendor/orig` with the corresponding patch applied, also tagged, e.g. `5.9p1+x509-7.1`
- `gert/develop` being the "daily development" branch, based off the `vendor/roumenpetrov`, now with a few local low-impact commits.
- `master` being the branch for release-ready code

My goals are basically this:

- Detectability of all changes in code. E.g. "Are we on 6.0p1 already in `master`?" -> `git branch --contains <commit-of-openssh-6.0p1>` yes/no answer.
- Easy upgrade of both OpenSSH as well as the patches from Roumen, with the least effort on conflicts with the local patches.
- View upgrades new versions as single commits: e.g. "Upgrade to patch to X509-7.4" along with "Upgrade to new upstream 6.0p1".

Practically I have an issue with the model above. Suppose I want to upgrade to 6.0p1 along with the corresponding new 7.4 patch from Roumen. What should I do? I found the following options:

- **upgrade, revert, upgrade, merge**

  1. In `vendor/orig`, upgrade the OpenSSH version.
  2. In `vendor/roumenpetrov`, revert the previous commit (`git revert 12345678`, the 7.1 patch).
  3. In `vendor/roumenpetrov`, merge with `vendor/orig`.
  4. In `vendor/roumenpetrov`, apply the new patch and commit.
  5. In `gert/develop`, merge with `vendor/roumenpetrov`

  Problems: 1) a lot of actions to take, 2) The revert action is a separate commit confusing when reading the log ("6.0p1 release" -> "revert X509 7.1" -> "merge vendor/orig" -> "apply X509 7.4".), 3) the revert with subsequent re-patch actions could cause more than ideal probability of conflicts, right?

  Plus side: `git log vendor/orig..vendor/roumenpetrov` shows me actual changes, although listing four commits.
- **same, but with `--no-commit`**

  1. In `vendor/roumenpetrov`: `git revert -n <patch-7.1>`
  2. In `vendor/roumenpetrov`: `git cherry-pick -n <openssh-6.0p1>`
  3. In `vendor/roumenpetrov`: `git commit` *magically* recognizes this as the the same commit as  from the message.

  Problem: `git log vendor/roumenpetrov..vendor/orig` shows openssh-6.0p1 not being applied because it has a different commit hash (diff=empty).
- **merge `--squash`**

  Problem: same as above, but for another reason.
- **rebase**

  Problem: we push this repository to a central (not-yet-public) location. Rebasing in the `vendor/roumenpetrov` branch on a newer `vendor/orig` is therefore not an option as far as I know if other people are working on this branch as well. This also holds for the other remote branches. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2219681/1254292) as for why I believe rebasing is not an option for my case.

  And, is it true what [svnpenn mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588112/how-do-i-manage-externally-maintained-patches-on-software-with-git#comment20373580_14593959)?

  > without a rebase you have no other choice than to do ugly merge commits.

---

So, taking a step back, what is my best option here to have this maintainable? Do I have to take sacrifices for the inevitable reason being the patch from Roumen depending on a specific OpenSSH version? Do I have to revise this whole branching model? Or am I missing out on something very basic?

Answer (score 1):

> The obvious upgrade of OpenSSH on top of the patched version is a plain merge
>   conflict and exactly what I want to avoid, yet keeping the upstream and patched
>   version distinct in Git.

The way I handle this is by keeping the changes on a separate branch

```
A--B--C
       \
        X--Y--Z
```

then if commits are made upstream

```
A--B--C--D--E--F
       \
        X--Y--Z
```

you can rebase the branch onto the new `HEAD`

```
 A--B--C--D--E--F
                 \
                  X'--Y'--Z'
```

this avoids merge commits, and will make it very easy to merge into master should the `upstream` people ever decide to do so.

[**ref**](http://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/Topic-Branches)

Comment: Yes, I know I can rebase, but that's not valid if I want to **push** this branch out. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2219681/1254292). So, this is not an answer to my question I believe.