# Git: getting changes from another branch

Tags: git

I have a project which uses git and I'd like to start a new branch to add a major new feature.

Under the `main` branch, I'll continue to add bug fixes and minor features. At regular intervals I'd like to pull the changes from the main branch into my "major new feature" branch. What's the best way to do this?

Eventually, I'll merge the "major new feature" branch into the main branch.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`git checkout featurebranch && git merge master`

You can do this as many times as you like; it won't affect master and you will be able to easily do it the other way around whenever you find out you are done with the feature branch.

Comment: `git rebase master` may be more desirable than `git merge master` for simplifying later integration back into the master branch.

Answer (score 114):

```
git checkout featurebranch && git rebase master
```

As long as you haven't pushed yet, it is better to replay your changes on top of master.

See:

- [git rebase vs. merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/git-rebase-vs-git-merge/804178#804178)
- [git workflow and rebase vs merge questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457927/git-workflow-and-rebase-vs-merge-questions/457988#457988)

Comment: Can you get more recent changes with git rebase, or only with git merge?

Comment: @keflavich since you are rebasing `featurebranch` on top of master, you are getting all the latest commits from `master`. A merge would be similar but will make for a slightly more complex integration with `master` later on.

Comment: hey! I'm a git newb, so can you go into more detail on `as long as you haven't pushed yet?` I've got a feature branch that I've pushed to a remote repo for backup. Can I keep doing `git rebase master`, then commit and push some work to my feature branch, then `git rebase master` ? I have to merge other feature branches into my branch as well too!

Comment: @GringoSuave Yes, if you are not the only one working on that feature branch. Generally, rebase only what you have not pushed yet (unless, again, you are the only one working on it)