# How To Merge Feature Branch Into New Feature Branch (Git)

Tags: git, merge

I want to merge a feature branch into a newly created feature branch.

My new branch was created off of the master branch and now I want to merge the changes from another feature branch into that new feature branch like this:

```
git merge feature/my-new-feature
```

However this did not work and I cannot find an answer that works. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were actually pretty close.

As described in this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613902/how-to-pull-from-a-local-branch-into-another-one).

First, position yourself on the branch where you want to merge : in your case "feature/my-new-feature".

Just run a :

```
git checkout feature/my-new-feature
```

Then you will want to do the actual merge telling git which branch contains the changes you want to merge into the current branch, in your case the "feature/my_first_feature". This is done with a :

```
git merge feature/my_first_feature
```