# Get changes from master into branch in Git

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge

In my repository I have a branch called `aq` which I'm working on.

I then committed new work and bugs in `master`.

What is the best way to get those commits into the `aq` branch? Create another new branch out of `master` and merge it with `aq`?

Comment: In the future, you could also start your bugfix branch from a common ancestor of master and other branches that will need the fixes, so that you can merge it into all of those branches, without picking anything else up.

Comment: @Jefromi but that's out of his control if he's not the sole person working on the project. other people update the master. hell, you yourself may update the master from a third branch, and the situation would be unavoidable, and in need of a general solution.

Comment: @ahnbizcad I'm pretty sure he's in control of where he starts his own branch. If his branch is a common ancestor of the ones he'll want to merge into, and people subsequently add to those branches, it'll still be a common ancestor.

Comment: guys question, does this command do it, `git pull origin my_branch_name`

Answer (score 1117, accepted):

Check out the `aq` branch, and rebase from `master`.

```
git checkout aq
git rebase master
```

Comment: can rebase come from any other branch?  Ie. git rebase otherbranch?  It seems I was a little off in my question, I branched from a branch then made changes to the original branch.

Comment: If im right, rebase on the pull request it will show all the master commits. if you use merge/origin master all master commits will be shown as 1 commit, which it makes it easier for code review.

Comment: Sometimes, `git merge` would be better. If both branches evolved over time, you should consider which is best for you.

Comment: Late to the party, but this is a great overview of when to rebase vs merge: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing/workflow-walkthrough

Comment: If your previous commits on branch aq are public then don't do rebase.

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase

Comment: NB: This will copy the commits to the `aq` branch, but also still leave the commits on `master`, which I presume wasn't your intention. So you'd have to rollback master to the commit before the ones you wanted to move, for instance by using `git stash` then `git reset --hard <SHA of last commit you want to keep>`, and then `git stash pop`

Comment: Here is one more thoughtful article on merging vs rebasing: http://kristopherwilson.com/2015/02/12/stop-merging-master/

Comment: Make sure to checkout master, pull latest changes and then change to feature branch. I forgot to do that and kept wondering why my changes weren't applying :P

Comment: if private branch and no one else see it, then use rebase, otherwise don't use it -> https://hackernoon.com/git-merge-vs-rebase-whats-the-diff-76413c117333

Answer (score 433):

You should be able to just `git merge origin/master` when you are on your aq branch.

```
git checkout aq
git merge origin/master
```

Comment: Merge isn't the ideal solution when you want to pull in changes from a parent branch. See the following for why rebase is better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457927/git-workflow-and-rebase-vs-merge-questions

Comment: If rebase is “better” depends completely on the specific situation.

Comment: origin master may have commits besides the bug fix commits.

Comment: why don't you just call "git merge master" instead of "git merge origin/master"?

Comment: Use `rebase` if your branch is local and hasn't been pushed to `origin`. Use `merge` if your branch is already pushed. `rebase` will rewrite history.

Comment: why don't you just call "git merge master" instead of "git merge origin/master"?

Comment: @Toskan you can run into issues where your local master isn't up to date with the remote. This way it insures that you are merging in the remote copy of the code.

Comment: @garbagecollector I am against rebase (I can, but won't rebase) I see no reason to gamble with rebase. It just makes things needlessly complex. You always have the question "Did I push this to remote?" to ponder and it is a pain to explain to newcomers. Some people say it avoids merge commits. But I *want* to have merge commits. They are not clutter, they document when branches are merged. So for the last time, can we finally stop acting like we are all committing to master? If you dislike merge commits in log so much, just filter them with --no-merges.

Comment: In the SVN world, we can specify date intervals. Is that the case in the Git world too? Let's suppose I am only interested in merging changes into my branch from master for the past 24 hours, how would I do this?

Comment: @MichaelKüller the only way ti avoid git merge origin/master would be to first do git checkout master and then do a git pull and then do git merge master. That way your local is in sync with remote master.

Comment: If you don't `git fetch` this will merge in your local git repo's understanding of where `origin/master` -- which could be behind what's live on the remote. There's a reason that `pull` runs `fetch` before it run `merge`.

Answer (score 134):

First check out to master:

```
git checkout master
```

Do all changes, hotfix and commits and push your master.

Go back to your branch, 'aq', and merge master in it:

```
git checkout aq
git merge master
```

Your branch will be up-to-date with master. A good and basic example of merge is *[3.2 Git Branching - Basic Branching and Merging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)*.

Comment: this is actually very dangerous if you don't know the "state" of your local master in respect of the origin shared across developer's Team and "push" them to orgin.

Answer (score 37):

There is no guarantee that the master bug fixes are not amongst other commits, hence you can't simply merge. Do

```
git checkout aq
git cherry-pick commit1
git cherry-pick commit2
git cherry-pick commit3
...
```

assuming those commits represent the bug fixes.

From now on though, keep bug fixes in a separate branch. You will be able to just

```
git merge hotfixes
```

when you want to roll them all into the regular dev branch.

Comment: Thank you, I'll steal your tip, and use from now on. I like this idea of bug fixes in a separate branch. Although, I'd maybe wanna separate out any bug fixes, known to cause more bugs (if possible) 

Answer (score 31):

This ([from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pulling?view=azure-devops&tabs=command-line#update-your-branch-with-the-latest-changes-from-master)) worked for me:

```
git checkout aq
git pull origin master
...
git push
```

Quoting:

> `git pull origin master` fetches and merges the contents of the master
>   branch with your branch and creates a merge commit. **If there are any
>   merge conflicts** you'll be notified at this stage and **you must resolve
>   the merge commits before proceeding**. When you are ready to push your
>   local commits, including your new merge commit, to the remote server,
>   run `git push`.

Comment: Important to note that this solution is perfect if a *merge* is required specifically, that is, if the master branch cannot be rebased for some reason.

Answer (score 22):

**Merge it with `aq`**

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout aq
git merge --no-ff master
git push
```

Comment: Why no fast forward?

Answer (score 21):

Scenario :

- I created a branch from master say branch-1 and pulled it to my local.
- My Friend created a branch from master say branch-2.
- He committed some code changes to master.
- Now I want to take those changes from master branch to my local branch.

Solution

```
git stash // to save all existing changes in local branch
git checkout master // Switch to master branch from branch-1
git pull // take changes from the master
git checkout branch-1 // switchback to your own branch
git rebase master // merge all the changes and move you git head  forward
git stash apply // reapply all you saved changes
```

> You can find conflicts on your file after executing "git stash apply". You need to fix it manually and now you are ready to push.

Comment: It's worth noting that if someone else has a branch branched from yours (or changes otherwise linked to your existing history), rebasing will be a nightmare. If your branch is purely local, this will be fine, but be careful rewriting history which is already published!

Answer (score 18):

Either `cherry-pick` the relevant commits into branch `aq` or merge branch `master` into branch `aq`.

Comment: @Slee you answered yourself... it's not the solution for this situation

Answer (score 9):

Easy way

```
# 1. Create a new remote branch A base on last master
# 2. Checkout A
# 3. Merge aq to A
```

Answer (score 8):

For me, I had changes already in place and I wanted the latest from the base branch.  I was unable to do `rebase`, and `cherry-pick` would have taken forever, so I did the following:

```
git fetch origin <base branch name>  
git merge FETCH_HEAD
```

so in this case:

```
git fetch origin master  
git merge FETCH_HEAD
```

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT:**

My answer below documents a way to merge `master` into `aq`, where if you view the details of the merge it lists the changes made on `aq` prior to the merge, not the changes made on `master`. I've realised that that probably isn't what you want, even if you think it is!

Just:

```
git checkout aq
git merge master
```

is fine.

Yes, this simple merge will show that the changes from `master` were made to `aq` at that point, not the other way round; but that is okay – since that is what did happen! Later on, when you finally merge your branch into `master`, that is when a merge will finally show all your changes as made to `master` (which is exactly what you want, and is the commit where people are going to expect to find that info anyway).

I've checked and the approach below also shows exactly the same changes (all the changes made on `aq` since the *original* split between `aq` and `master`) as the normal approach above, when you finally merge everything back to `master`. So I think its only real disadvantage (apart from being over-complex and non-standard... :-/ ) is that if you wind back n recent changes with `git reset --hard HEAD~<n>` and this goes past the merge, then the version below rolls back down the 'wrong' branch, which you have to fix up by hand (e.g. with `git reflog` & `git reset --hard [sha]`).

---

[So, what I previously thought was that:]

There is a problem with:

```
git checkout aq
git merge master
```

because the changes shown in the merge commit (e.g. if you look now or later in Github, Bitbucket or your favourite local git history viewer) are the changes made on master, which may well not be what you want.

On the other hand

```
git checkout master
git merge aq
```

shows the changes made in aq, which probably *is* what you want. (Or, at least, it's often what I want!) But the merge showing the right changes is on the wrong branch!

How to cope?!

The full process, ending up with a merge commit showing the changes made on aq (as per the second merge above), but with the merge affecting the aq branch, is:

```
git checkout master
git merge aq
git checkout aq
git merge master
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git checkout aq
```

This: merges aq onto master, fast-forwards that same merge onto aq, undoes it on master, and puts you back on aq again!

I feel like I'm missing something - this seems to be something you'd obviously want, and something that's hard to do.

Also, rebase is NOT equivalent. It loses the timestamps and identity of the commits made on aq, which is also not what I want.

Comment: If you are not ready to merge aq into master yet, this cannot be a solution. Very important spokesperson if others are on your project. It also seems to defeat the purpose of a separate branch.

Comment: (Spokesperson? Autocorrect typo?) Anyway, this solution is about merging some changes from `master` into `aq`, as per the original question, so I'm not sure I understand the problem you're suggesting? Certainly, you could eventually merge `aq` later to `master`, after doing either of the above solutions I mention, and after then committing further changes to both - it would cause no issues.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple options. `git rebase master aq`onto the branch which will keep the commit names, but DO NOT REBASE if this is a remote branch. You can `git merge master aq` if you don't care about keeping the commit names. If you want to keep the commit names and it is a remote branch `git cherry-pick <commit hash>` the commits onto your branch.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by running a single line.
`git merge aq master`

This is equivalent to

```
git checkout aq
git merge master
```

Comment: This is not doing what you think it is doing. `git merge a b` merges branches `a` and `b` into the current branch. But `git merge a` when you are on branch `a` will do nothing (which is why this looks a bit like it's doing what you think it's doing). (See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt-ltcommitgt82308203 .)

Answer (score 1):

Just to distinguish between `git merge` and `git rebase`:

Scenario:

- you made a feature branch
- you made some commits to it
- you (or someone else) made changes to `main`
- you want the changes in `main` to be reflected in the feature branch

Switch to the feature branch (`git checkout your-feature-branch`), then:

- **`git merge`** integrates the two branches by creating a new commit that has two parent commits: one from the `main` branch and one from the feature branch.
- **`git rebase`** will essentially move or "replay" your feature branch's commits so that they appear *after* the latest commit on main.

Answer (score -1):

```
1.git stash - apply this when you have uncommitted changes
2.git checkout master 
3.git pull 
4.git checkout branch1 (branch1 - Your working branch)
5.git rebase master 
6.git stash apply - apply whether you stashed uncommitted changes
```

You might find merging conflicts after applying stashes. Solve it manually