# Merging small change into branch

Tags: git, version-control, branching-and-merging, rebase

I currently have a stable master branch, and a branch with a lot of big changes on certain classes.

While using the "changes" branch, I discovered a bug I also want to fix on the master branch.

I fixed it by changing only one line of code on the master.

Now, I want to have this hotfix also added onto the "changes" branch.

[Reading some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340724/get-changes-from-master-into-branch-in-git), it's been suggested that the best option would be to Rebase.

When applying `git rebase master` on the "changes" branch, though, git seems to consider one of the 
conflicting files a completely different file than before. Using `mergetools --tool diffuse`, I get the following diagnostic:

[image]

As you can see, there's one change in the first file, tons of changes in the second, and apparently no overlap between anything.

My question is: Is there a way to merge a *small change* into a heavily altered branch, without having to spend a lot of effort into conflict resolution? If not, what's the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: For one-line changes, cherry-picking is the way to go.

Comment: For the heavily-altered part, it's only going to get worse.  When the time comes it might be worth checking into imerge - I've never used it in anger myself but it does seem well thought out and popular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the cherry-pick method user3387542 suggests, it's a good way to do it, just not the only way. Another is, since the bug also exists on the master branch the most recent merge base for the two also has it.

```
git checkout $(git merge-base master changes)
# fix bug at the last branchpoint
git commit -m 'fix bug #27182'
git branch bugfix-27182

git checkout master
git merge bugfix-27182

git checkout changes
git merge bugfix-27182

# git branch -d bugfix-27182
```

There's downsides either way, you're balancing commit-graph clutter with clear traceability (it's easy to say `git branch --contains $somecommit` to find out which branches contain the fix, not so easy nor so certain to look for equivalent commits but a much cleaner-looking history.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on the command git cherry-pick. Here more details about it:

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

We often use it, to copy bugfixes to other branches containing different releases. It's a great feature.