# Git: how to update branch with master?

Tags: git

This is my situation:

- I have started a new branch (let's call it `foo`) and did some work on that,
- I have pushed `foo` to remote
- something needed to be done on `master`, so I switched to master, did the fixes and pushed,

Now: how do I update `foo` with `master`? Because I need to work on `foo`, but I want it to be aligned with the changes in `master`. I understand I am not supposed to `rebase` a branch that has been published...

Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply use `merge`?

Comment: Merge from master to branch, test, correct, commit, then merge from branch to master.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get changes from master into branch in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340724/get-changes-from-master-into-branch-in-git)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Good that you know you should not rebase and force-push a published branch.

You need the changes of `master` into `foo`? The most natural thing to do here is to do just that. Merge the changes of `master` into `foo`.

Your situation:

```
o---o---o - master
     \-o---o---o - foo
```

then:

```
$ git checkout foo
$ git merge master
```

leads to a new merge commit `m` in `foo`:

```
o---o---o---------- - master
     \             \
      \-o---o---o---m - foo
```

It is clear from the history what you did, and probably why. You can even mention what you needed from `master` in the commit message of `m`.

Answer (score 0):

Either merge `master` from `foo`

```
git checkout foo
git merge master
```

Or, if `foo` is not used by other developers and you have authorization to force a push on the remote, then you can rebase it and force-push it :

```
git checkout foo
git rebase master
git push -f remote
```

There is no danger in rebasing and force-pushing already published commits as long as you know that **nobody** except you has planned to work on or from those commits until they fetch your rebased-then-published commits. Next time your colleagues  fetch from the remote, they will see that `foo` was updated by force, just that.

Comment: Your merge merges `foo` into `master`?