# Git pull master into remote branch on origin

Tags: git, github

I have a two remote branches: `origin/master` and `origin/my_remote_feature`

I have checked out `my_remote_feature` using `git checkout --track -b origin/my_remote_feature`

There are a couple of changes made in master that I want to pull into my branch that tracks the remote branch. How do I go about it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get changes from master into branch in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340724/get-changes-from-master-into-branch-in-git)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
git rebase origin/master
```

Is all you really need to do. then resolve any conflicts. You might need

```
git rebase --continue
```

if there are are conflicts. This will put my_remote_feature commits on top of the HEAD of origin/master. Re-writing history as it were.

```
git merge origin/master
```

Is also a possibility. However, you will find that all the commits to master will become part of your remote_feature commit history. Which you may not want. Generally rebase is better to keep your commit history pristine. :)

Answer (score 2):

One cool way to do this is to rebase origin/master into your remote branch. You can follow the following rebase workflow;

1. Check out to your local my_remote_feature branch and pull changes from that branch. `git pull origin my_remote_feature`
2. Do a `git fetch`
3. Then rebase origin/master like `git rebase origin/master`
4. If all works successfully, push your new updates. `git push origin my_remote_feature`

This will bring all the changes on master on top of your changes in my_remote_feature. If there are any conflicts, you will have to resolve them along the way and make sure you add files after resolving conflicts then do a `git rebase --continue` after every conflict resolutions.

You can refer to [the git rabase doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Merge the `master` branch to your feature branch and then push the changes.