# Git merge updated develop branch into local branch

Tags: git, git-merge

How do I go about updating a branch that I have checked out, with the updated (which has had a few pull requests merged, after the local branch was branched off of develop) develop branch ?
At the moment, if I am on `branch_1` with un/committed/pushed changes, I do a

```
git checkout develop
git pull
git checkout branch_1
git merge develop
```

Is there a way with lesser steps to achieve what I am after ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get changes from master into branch in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340724/get-changes-from-master-into-branch-in-git)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to update `branch_1` via merging, then there is a slightly shorter version of doing this:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout branch_1
git merge origin/develop
```

By doing a `git fetch`, you automatically update the remote tracking branch for `develop`, which is called `origin/develop`.  Note that the local branch `develop` would *not* be updated, but it doesn't matter, because you can merge with the tracking branch.

Comment: Can't edit the answer but the last command is `git merge origin/develop`