# GIT how to put changes i made from master to dev branch?

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch

So I forked a repo now I made changes to master branch and sent pull request, I made a mistake because they want the changes to be done in a different branch, the `dev` branch.

How do I put the changes from master to dev and send pull request again?

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340724/get-changes-from-master-into-branch-in-git

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get changes from master into branch in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340724/get-changes-from-master-into-branch-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

assuming :

- you are pushing to your repo (not a shared one)
- you are on head of your branch (where your job is finished)

Use some graphical tool to help you seeing if every thing goes well (gitk ; doing "shift F5" to refresh view , is a good option)

```
# on top of your dev : first create the dev branch
git checkout -b <dev-branch-name>
# then you must rewind where you would like master to be master
git checkout <sha 1 of position where master should be>
# at this point assign master head to here
git branch -f master
# now you have to push the two branches
# 1st dev branch
git push <remote-name> <dev-branch-name>
# then master note the -f force option
git push -f <remote-name> master
```

At each point you check in the graphical tool tool that it does what is expected

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `cherry-pick`?

I will assume that your current branch is `master`. If so, You check for the commit ID that you really want to commit to the `dev` using `git log`. Then you see the commit logs like this:

```
commit ca82a6dff817ec66f44342007202690a93763949
Author: AuthorName < author@gee-mail.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 17 21:52:11 2008 -0700

    changed the version number

commit 085bb3bcb608e1e8451d4b2432f8ecbe6306e7e7
Author: AuthorName < author@gee-mail.com>
Date:   Sat Mar 15 16:40:33 2008 -0700

    removed unnecessary test code
```

If you want to apply the commit `085bb3bcb608e1e8451d4b2432f8ecbe6306e7e7` to the `dev`.

and

```
git checkout dev
git cherry-pick 085bb3bcb608e1e8451d4b2432f8ecbe6306e7e7
```

After that, you can send pull request again.