# Avoid unwanted merge commits and other commits when doing pull request on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I forked a project on Github.

Let the remote upstream be `upstream` and my remote repository be `origin`.
My local `master` branch is set to track the remote `master` branch.
Then I added some stuff in local `master`, and I merged with the upstream every now and then.

Not until today when I want to issue a pull request did I find the problem:
the pull request consists those **merge commits**, and those **unwanted commits** that I did previously without care. However what I want is just to submit the last commit I did, which should be pulled as a single commit.
What can I do to rescue this?

Answer (score 28):

Instead of merging you want to rebase. You can do this manually, or automatically when pulling.

```
git pull --rebase upstream master
git push --force origin master
```

Once you've started doing merges though this will get hard to do, you'll need to reset the branch back to before you did a merge commit.

Comment: This one seems work. I am just not sure if I have to do step two, since every time I merge with remote master there will be a merge commit.

Comment: -1 for the git push --force solution to be offered on the same level as git push --rebase. User needs to be warned of the possible pitfalls with push --force which is potentially more damaging, and other users of the repo must know how to react correctly if they branched off a commit that was entirely removed by the push --force and want to merge back

Answer (score 11):

If I understand your question, you want to get rid of the intermediate/throwaway commits that you did in your branch. Try something like this:

```
git checkout -b for-upstream remotes/origin/master (create a new branch from the upstream origin)
git cherry-pick <sha-of-the-one-commit-you-want-to-submit> (fix any conflicts if necessary)
```

this should give you a local "for-upstream" branch which contains just the upstream master + your 1 commit. You can then submit that branch for pull request

Comment: I think the first line needs to be `git checkout -b ...` and not `git branch -b ...` (make that change and I'll up-vote this here answer)

Answer (score 6):

On Github, You can't create a pull request for a single specific checkin on a branch that has multiple checkins separating it from upstream.

Create a branch specifically for each pull request you intend to make. This allows you to continue working without fear of polluting a pull request.

Answer (score 3):

Would this work:
Create a separate branch with just the commit you want and issue a pull request on that branch.

Comment: This is what I'd recommend.  Don't be afraid of merge commits though, if the branch contained just that single commit you wanted pulled and a bunch of merges to keep it up to date with master, there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: This is exactly what I am asking -- I don't know how to do this appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an answer to your question (section "Update 2011-04-15" of the topic):

[Git workflow and rebase vs merge questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457927/git-workflow-and-rebase-vs-merge-questions)

Micah describes the technique of *squash merges* which let you merge changes from your feature branch as a single commit to the master branch.

Comment: Squash merges destroy merge tracking and can cause no end of pain.