# How do I clean up my Github fork so I can make clean pull requests?

Tags: git, github

I forked a repository on Github. I've made some minor changes and submitted pull requests to the upstream, but along the way my fork has become so mangled I'm unable to generate clean pull requests; when I start a pull request from a branch with six changes, Github wants to submit thirteen, with seven of them already existing upstream (natch).

My problem seems to be related to [only pulling the latest commits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5561161/306084), but when I create a new branch and cherry-pick commits I still have extras. I've futzed with [rebasing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3867284/306084) as well, but now it looks like even [my master](https://github.com/pjmorse/sproutguides) is so messed up I can't generate a clean copy of [upstream](https://github.com/sproutcore/sproutguides). This is apparently because I didn't understand that I needed to [rebase instead of merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968964/avoid-unwanted-merge-commits-and-other-commits-when-doing-pull-request-in-github/5969100#5969100), so clearly I've made mistakes; what I'm trying to do is figure out how to unsnarl that knot and get back to a clean state where I can move forward usefully.

I kind of want to blow away my fork and make a new fork of the upstream, but I gather that, too, is difficult.

Having confessed my Git sins, how do I obtain github absolution?

Comment: Love your confession and request for being absolved :-)

Comment: What, there are people for whom git isn't a religion? ;-)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

**Step 1: Pull upstream changes**
It's recommended to add the upstream repo as "upstream" as explained on the [Fork a Repo](http://help.github.com/fork-a-repo/) page:

```
git pull --rebase upstream master
```

The `--rebase` option places your changes on top of the latest commit without merges.

**Step 2: (Optional) Merge your commits into 1 commit**

```
git reset --soft upstream/master
```

This command will "undo" all your commits, but won't change the files. So you can commit all your changes in a single commit.

```
git commit -a
```

**Step 3: Check & test your changes**

To show the changes use a GUI like the built-in `gitk`, [Sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com), [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) or [Tower](https://www.git-tower.com) *(paid)*, etc.

**Step 4: Push**

`git push` will throw an error, because the push would change the target repository's history.
If you're confident the changes shown in step 3 are correct then push with "-f"

```
git push -f origin master
```

**Additional information**
The command to add a remote is:

```
git remote add upstream git://github.com/[username]/[project].git
```

You can also also pull from a direct URL:

```
git pull --rebase  git://github.com/[username]/[project].git
```

But then you'll need the hash of the latest upstream commit instead of "upstream/master" in the other steps.

Comment: Thank you very much. GitHub should update their [Fork A Repo](http://help.github.com/fork-a-repo/).

Comment: Hi, @JudahHimango. Have you followed the "step 2" too. Because I'm in the same situation like you. Can you help me.

Comment: My forked repo kept saying it was out of sync with the upstream, so I would pull down and merge - which lead to commits on my fork that weren't necessary.

Using this approach and forcing the push has sorted this.  I also used rebase to combine some of my earlier commits:

     git rebase -i HEAD~n [where n is the number of commits]

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it, with both Git and Mercurial (I've only used the latter, so I may be wrong) it isn't a big deal at all to blow away a fork and re-fork it. I do that all the time with my projects. If you're ok with doing that (can back up your changes, or don't have any significant changes in your fork), I'd say that's probably the way to go.

Remember, with DVCS, forking a repository makes a full clone of that *entire repo*. If you delete your current fork and then fork the original repo again, you'll have a completely clean slate to work from.

Comment: Fork in this case is a special feature of github, not core git, though it uses core git features.  There are special github administrative abilities you can do with github-forks.

Comment: Ah, I see. I use BitBucket primarily, and on there "Fork" is synonymous with "clone" when you're working with personal working copies. I'll leave my answer here anyway though just in case.

Comment: Yeah, I've deleted my local clone and re-cloned several times already. I did an experiment with another repo and it looks like there isn't a problem with deleting a fork and creating a new one from the same source.

Comment: N.B. I'm using `git format-patch` to preserve the commits I want to save first.

Comment: Deleting your forked repository and reforking is unnecessary, and using `git format-patch` to save your work is sort of side-stepping all the helpful tools that git has for managing branches.  In the future, using `git rebase -i` to selectively rewrite your commits on the top of the new upstream `master` branch is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

On your private repo, add the forkee's repo as a remote.  Rebase/reset your branches from the remote's branches.  Do a force push to your github repo.

If you need exact commands, let me know.  Also let me know whether you want to try and preserve local commits or if "blowing away" is OK.