# Github: How do I pull unmerged upstream pull requests in to my fork?

Tags: git, github

Situation:

- There is a repo on Github: http://github.com/otheruser/reponame.  This repo has 24 unmerged pull requests.
- I have forked it to http://github.com/myusername/reponame.

Problem:

- The upstream repo seems to be unmaintained because some of those pull requests are a year or more old.
- I want some of those 24 unmerged pull requests in my fork, but can't figure out how to get them.  (I would be willing to accept them all, if it's not possible to take only some.)

I have not made any changes to my fork, so it's basically a clone of the upstream repo.  It seems like this should be pretty straightforward, but I can't quite figure it out.  I've tried a handful of approaches, but none quite seem to work.

- After cloning my fork to my local machine, I was able to gain access to the pull requests using the approach outlined [here](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/wiki/Landing-Pull-Requests).  However, when I attempted to merge the branches, it failed.
- Likewise, I tried to create patches directly from Github, but `git am` failed to apply them successfully.

Thanks in advance for your help!

P.S. This question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102297/how-do-i-clean-up-my-github-fork-so-i-can-make-clean-pull-requests) with no response.

Comment: What message do you get when attempting to merge the branches?

Comment: Have you tried to contact the repo owner asking them if they are willing to reassign the repo to you?

Comment: @JosefAssad: yes, but the owner has not responded to my email.

Comment: @r3m0t unfortunately, i've lost those errors

Comment: Well, why don’t you just try to merge again and show us the error?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding the repos that sent the pull requests as remotes, and merging their master/whatever branch into your master branch?

Comment: This has the drawback that the pull request authors are not made aware their pull requests have made it into the codebase.

Comment: If he pushes back to github, I suspect they'll show up in the original repo's network and the pulls' authors will get a notification.

Comment: Yes, merging those pull requests and pushing to github will add a note to the pull request.

Comment: I tried this (`git remote add upstream (url)`, `git fetch upstream pull/(number)/head:pr(number)`, `git merge pr(number)`, `git push`) and no note was added to the pull request.  It did merge the upstream PR correctly, though.