# How to apply unmerged pull request from original repo into my fork via GitHub website

Tags: git, github

Trying to do this via the GitHub website.

I am aware of
[How to apply unmerged upstream pull requests from other forks into my fork?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022302/how-to-apply-unmerged-upstream-pull-requests-from-other-forks-into-my-fork)
and
[Github: How do I pull unmerged upstream pull requests in to my fork?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254378/github-how-do-i-pull-unmerged-upstream-pull-requests-in-to-my-fork)
but these two are not about doing this via the GitHub website.

So I have made a fork of this repo.
https://github.com/saabi/vminpoly/
For my understanding this is the original repo.

Now when looking at my fork I obviously do not see the unmerged pull requests from the original repo.

Going to my fork I  can see the exact copy of the original repo. However I am at loss trying to get a selection of pull requests from the original repo to appear in my fork via the website. Is this possible at all?

For example how can I get this unmerged pull request
https://github.com/saabi/vminpoly/pull/29
to appear in my fork and then of course merge it in my fork?

Can someone please tell me what exactly I need to select to get the mentioned pull request to appear in my fork and then subsequently I can merge it in my forked version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found that this is not possible via the website since the fork with the pull request was **deleted**.

If the original fork where the pull request came from is **deleted** then one **has to use the command line** in order to modify an inactive pull request locally.

https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/#modifying-an-inactive-pull-request-locally