# Github: Clean up fork after pull request

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-fork

I have forked a github repository, made a commit (title `Some small changes`), submitted a pull request and it got merged into the main repository (commit title `Some small changes (#12)`, where `#12` is the pull request number). So far, so good.

Now, when I want to update my fork (`git rebase upstream/master`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-do-i-update-a-github-forked-repository)), I have this commit twice in my repository. First as `Some small changes` and then again as `Some small changes (#12)`. If I create a new pull request, the `Some small changes` commit is again added to the pull request.

There are two ways to work around this issue:

1. Clean up my fork, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9646323/4920424)
2. Merge all commits into one, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6103022/4920424)

Both cases involve rewriting my history and having to force-push. Is there a better way to keep your fork in sync while committing pull requests?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. I would assume there are a few ways to do this but here is what I do.

So you want to contribute to a repository on github, lets call this `upstream`.

On github, you would fork the `upstream` repository. Let's call this one `origin`.

Then on your development machine you would clone `origin` so you can work on the code. Let's call this one `local`. When you clone this repository, you very likely already have `origin` set up as a Remote Repository. You will also need to add the `upstream` repository as a Remote Repository.

Then when you want to make a change, don't make this change on the `master` branch. Instead create a new branch for your changes. i.e `fix-issue-101`

Once you are happy with the changes you have made, you will want to push your changes from the `local` repository to the `origin` repository.
You can now create a Pull Request on `upstream` from the `fix-issue-101` branch on `origin` to the `master` branch on `upstream`.

You can continue creating branches on `local` and `origin` while you wait for the Pull Request to be accepted, and hence create additional Pull Requests.

When `master` on `upstream` has changes, i.e. your Pull Request was accepted, you would pull from `master` on `upstream` to `master` on `local`. You then push `master` on `local` to `master` on `origin`. After doing so, the `master` branches of all repositories will be back in sync.

I hope I've written this in an understandable manner. If not feel free to ask questions and I'll update accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much, the answer is quite clear and a much better approach than the one I used before.

Comment: This is a great answer, clear and doesn't assume knowledge of origin and upstream, local terminology.

Comment: Plus, GitHub let's you delete the remote branch with one click once the pull request has been merged. The "delete branch" button will appear at the bottom of the Pull Request page once it is merged.