# Proper git workflow scheme with multiple developers working on same task

Tags: git, workflow, bitbucket, branching-and-merging

I'm a team leader in our web development company, and I'd like to implement Git workflow in our team. Reading documentation and articles I've found the following structure good for us:

We have a repository in a Bitbucket. **Master** branch is considered to contain stable code only. Every dev must create his own branch and implement features/bugfixes in his **own** branch. Once he decides, that his code is ready, he creates a nice branch history (using rebase, amend, cherry-pick etc.) and pushes it to Bitbucket, where creates a pull request to master branch. QA verifies functionality and approves (or disapproves) it, then I'm verifying code and if it is ok, I merge his work into master (by fast-forward or rebasing for better commits history).

But this scheme is good only in a case, when single developer works on a branch. In our case we almost always have two developers for one branch, since one developer is working on *server-side* (PHP), and another - *client-side* (HTML/CSS/JS). How these two should collaborate in a way, that commit history in master stays clean?

Server dev creates basic structure of HTML files and client dev needs to get this structure. Logically would be for server dev to create a branch, and for client dev to create his own branch, based on server dev branch. But this means, that server dev needs to *publish* his branch in Bitbucket, which will make it *impossible for him to rebase or change commits*, that are already published.

Another option is to wait, until server dev finishes his work, publishes branch with nice commits history and forgets about it, and only after that client dev starts to work in this branch, but this will cause time delays, which is even worse.

How do you handle such a collaboration in your workflows?

Comment: There is no need for the server developer to publish in Bitbucket.  He can "publish" in other ways, and the client dev can pull from the other location.  (They could email bundles to each other, or pull directly, or use a different common server...)  You still have issues with a rebase, but it is now confined to 2 developers.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, yes, that may be an option, which I was thinking about as well, but I didn't want to involve 3rd-side solutions, like emailing, common server or whatever. Direct pulling seems one of preferable ways, but may complicate client-dev, since he will need to pull from Bitbucket and all the server-devs, he is working with - there will be a mess with all the remotes. Thank you for an advise!

Comment: "which will make it impossible for him to rebase or change commits" why is that? Your SCM should not be enforcing such rules on personal branches. Change your SCM so that only `master` is protected from rewrites.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

I can't really speak to the merits of the methods described in your post, but I can describe how we solved collaborative coding in the workflow we use at work.

The workflow we use is one of many branches. Our structure is thus:

Master is golden; only the merge master touches it (more on this in a bit).

There is a dev branch, taken initially from master, that all devs work off. Instead of having a branch per developer, we make feature, or ticket, branches from dev.

For every discreet feature (bug, enhancement, etc.), a new local branch is made from dev. Developers don't have to work on the same branch, since each feature branch is scoped to only what that single developer is working on. This is where git's cheap branching comes in handy.

Once the feature is ready, it's merged locally back into dev and pushed up to the cloud (Bitbucket, Github, etc.). Everyone keeps in sync by pulling on dev often.

We are on a weekly release schedule, so every week, after QA has approved the dev branch, a release branch is made with the date in the name. That is the branch used in production, replacing last week's release branch.

Once the release branch is verified by QA in production, the release branch is merged back into master (and dev, just to be safe). This is the only time we touch master, ensuring that it is as clean as possible.

This works well for us with a team of 12.

Comment: Thank you for description of your flow! I think, we can take this as base for our flow. I like the idea of 'release' branch, since issues, that left for upcoming release, will be solved in it, but a new features may be developed in 'development' branch without interferring with release stuff. The only thing, that disturbs me - pull requests will be useless here and code review must be organized in a different way.

Comment: No problem, glad it was helpful! In regards to the pull requests issue, it's true we don't use pull requests in our model, so I don't know how they would work using this method. However, in theory you could still make a local ticket branch off dev and use that as your pull request. Also, maybe consider using patches (`git format-patch`). This is the workflow that drupal.org uses.

Comment: I think, that I'll change scheme to post-review from pre-review. There will be a mandatory rule for devs to add Jira's issue number to every commit, that they push on a Bitbucket server, so I can see at any time all the commits, related to any issue, and reopen it, if I don't like some of the commits. This will not make me act as bottleneck in a project, since I'll not have to verify every single change, before it comes to 'develop' branch.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. We actually add the ticket name as the start of the title of our commit messages, aka `MY-PROJECT-13: message`, just like you're suggesting. Adding it at the start of the title has the added benefit that the Jira Git plugin picks up the ticket name and assigns the commit to the ticket in Jira (it is case sensitive, though).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly, what I'm thinking about. Many thanks for your tips! It could be a painfull path, until I finally land on this scheme :)

Comment: What happens if multiple people are working on a ticket and a branch exists for that ticket? Doesn't it mean that you're going to have multiple people working on the same branch? How does that work?

Comment: @Ogen This workflow assumes that you will be breaking larger tasks down into small enough chunks so that only one developer is working on that particular feature branch at a time. This keeps things sane in my experience. The larger work still gets done on the overarching task, but it is broken down into manageable chunks that single developers take on. Everyone can stay up to date by frequently merging the dev branch, and merge into dev when the feature is complete.

Comment: Great workflow, I like this method of working with multiple developers on same project.

Comment: Great workflow. I am absolutely going to share and implement this with my team. Question - Would not it be better to have an individual remote developer branch, just to keep the progress safe while they work on a feature? Suppose a developer needs around 2 weeks to complete a feature. S/he gets the latest pull of ‘origin/dev’ and creates her/his ‘local/feature-abc’ from the ‘local/dev’ branch. The developer plans to merge the code with dev branch and push it to remote dev after completing the task. Now if by some unfortunate event, the code gets deleted. All the progress of the dev is lost.

Comment: Hi Murtuza, thanks for posting. Yes, in this workflow - or any git workflow, I would argue - you would sync all local branches with the remote copy at least once a day, to save against disaster. If a dev is working on a larger feature, they should keep pulling the remote dev branch and either merging (easier, messier history) or rebasing (harder, clean history) the dev branch into their local branch to keep the eventual local branch merge clean. Hope that helps!

Comment: what about merge conflicts? what if the dev branch constantly updates from master and developers face merge conflicts all the time?

Answer (score 9):

I think still nobody actually answered the original question of how to collaborate in topic branches maintaining a clean history.

The proper answer is *sorry, you can't have all that together*. You only can groom your private local history, after you publish something for others you should work on top of that.

The best you could do in your particular case where server dev doesn't care about client dev changes is to locally fork client branches from dev/feature ones and rebase that part on top of server work just before finishing the feature —or relax your constraints and switch to a different workflow, as you did ;)

Comment: Thank you for the input. More than a year passed ater this question was asked, and I can add, that we stick to Git Flow now and trying to make our feature branches lifetime not really long. No strict rules are aplied for feature branches, except commit messages. This scheme is not ideal, but quite smooth and proved it's reliability.

Comment: You are welcome. Maybe this answer also could help with your feature branches history cleanup: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23476398/1385678

Comment: @DiegoV  So true.  The answers given so far, focus on the big picture. What if two developers are working on a single feature that will take several sprints?  Simple question that is about daily collaboration.

Answer (score 7):

We have a principal repository and each developer has a fork of that.

A branch is created principal/some_project, the same branch name is then created on each developers' fork, fork/some_project.

(We use smartgit and we also have a policy that remotes are named 'principal' and 'fork' rather than 'origin' and 'upstream' which just confuse new users).

Each developer also has a local branch named some_project.

The developers local branch some_project tracks the remote branch principal/some_project.

Developers do their local work on branch some_project and push-to to their fork/some_project, from time to time they create pull requests, this is how each developer's work gets merged into principal/some_project.

This way developers are free to pull/rebase locally and push to their forks - this is pretty much the standard fork workflow. This way they get other developers' commits and may from time to time have to resolve the odd conflict.

This is fine and all that's needed now is a way to merge in ongoing updates that appear in principal/master (for example urgent fixes or other projects that are delivered before some_project is finished).

To acomplish this we designate a 'branch lead' their role is to locally merge updates from master into some_project using merge (not pull, rebase) in SmartGit. This too may sometimes generate conflicts and these must be resolved. Once this is done that developer (the branch lead) force pushes to their fork/some_project branch then creates a pull request to merge into principal/some_project.

Once that pull request is merged, all of the new commits that were on principal/master are now present on the principal/some_project branch (and nothing was rebased).

Therefore the next time each developer is on some_project and pulls (recall, their tracked branch is principal/some_project) they'll get all of the updates which will include the stuff merged from principal/master.

This may sound long winded but it's actually fairly simple and robust (every developer could also just merge locally from principal/master but it's neater if one person does that, the rest of the team live in a simple world much like the single developer workflow).

Answer (score 6):

The rules to remember are:

- Have 1 `master` and 1 `develop` branch
- Have feature branches spawn off of `develop` branch
- Every time you have version ready for **QA** to test, merge into `develop`
- Have release branches spawn off of `develop` branch
- Make bugfixes into release branches
- When you have version ready for **QA** to test, merge into `develop`
- When you have version ready for **PRODUCTION**, merge into `master`, and create a tag for it

Following diagram is the bull's eye strategy followed in teams across the world (Credit: taken from [here](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)):

[image]

Comment: SCM is such a complex domain than the only reasonable way to end a sentence starting with "The rules to remember are..." is "...use an SCM tool."

Nearly everything else is project-, team-, workflow- and/or company-specific.

Comment: The QA tests off the release branch or the develop branch? The diagram does not show bug fix branches spawning off the release branches.. Does the release bug fix happen directly in release branch without a separate bug fix branch?

Answer (score 3):

> which will make it impossible for him to rebase or change commits, that are 
>   already published.

This depends on your audience. "Server dev" can push the "basic structure" to Bitbucket so that "client dev" will have access to it. **Yes this does potentially** mean that others will have access to these "temporary" commits.

However this would only be an issue if another user branched from one of these commits **before** they were rebased. On a smaller project/smaller userbase these temporary commits might never be noticed even before the rebase occured, hence negating the risk.

The decision is yours if the risk of someone branching from these temporary commits is too great. If so then you would need to perhaps create a second private Bitbucket repo for these private changes. Another option would be to do [**merge commits**](http://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/Topic-Branches)
instead of rebasing, but this is also not ideal.

Comment: Thank you for your tips. I was hezitating long between your solution and solution of @bronzehedwick, but decided to re-organize my developed flow before it is not too late :)

Answer (score 3):

For the exact question, multiple developers on the same task, the short answer is the task is done in an integration branch for that task. That 'task' branch is treated just like "master" or "dev" branches in the usual Git workflows (as most answers here provided).  This integration branch is processed in the "Git Feature Branch Workflow" elaborated elsewhere.

This task branch is where the devs working on that task share code using the normal Git commands.

**Example**

To develop the new splash screen, the Lead developer (or someone) does

```
git co master
git co -b feature-splash
git push origin feature-splash
```

Each developer working on this feature does:

```
git co master
git pull
git co feature-splash
git co -b my-feature-splash  // they can name their branch whatever
```

Now each dev will develop on their branch and create pull requests toward merges on the feature-splash on the central Git repo server like GitHub. Just like it is done for the sacrosanct 'master' branch.

When the feature is done, the feature-splash is merged into master. Of course, this feature-splash must be kept up to date with new code on master. Could the feature-splash use rebasing on master?

This is not my original idea.  I read about this in various places. Note that in many workflow articles this task specific branch is not really a concept. For example, in one article we have "Feature branches typically exist in developer repos only, not in origin." Perhaps a task that requires more than one developer is always broken down into subtasks?  I guess if you know the future and know what is required.

Answer (score 1):

You might see [Git-flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) this may help you

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: Thank you for an advise! I've tsarted thinking of changing of developed branches structure and involve 'development' with 'release' branches.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged because the links can die over time

Answer (score 1):

Let me tell you what we do here while multiple developers working on the same project (even sometimes working on the same controllers/models/views).

First of all our team-lead created git-project with two branches

1. Master (it is protected one, no one can push here except team-lead)
2. Development (all developers can push here)

They told us to work on our local environment and create commits whenever we completed one of assigned task(s).

Now in the evening-time (or say closing time - leaving), we do this :

1. Git Pull

Every developer that are working on the same project Pull current development branch to their local (do same in morning - when starting for day).

Then team-lead told developer to commit all codes and push one by one followed by one pull.

For ex.

- dev1 creates commit and pushes to server
- dev2 pulls again and creates commit and push
- dev3 pulls again and creates commit and push
- and so on..

Now the problem is conflicts :

- Sometime while pulling code from development branch git notifies that we merged all conflicts automatically --- that means git automatically applied new changes made by another developer
- But sometime the SAME git tells that automatic merge failed and shows some filenames
- then team-lead role comes into picture -- what he does is : "He reviews all listed files (during automatic merge failed process) and merges conflicts manually and creates commit and push to server.

Now how to merge manually : GIT simply updates conflict files with all contents like this :

```
<<< HEAD
New lines from server that you don't have is here shown
=====
Your current changes....
>>> [commit id]
```

Team-lead updates that file after analyzing to this :

```
 New lines from server that you don't have is here shown
 Your current changes
```

and creates commit and push.

Again in morning we do pull (just to make sure that we didn't miss anything from previous day), This is how we work here.

Comment: Won't it be really troublesome if the number of developers increase a lot?

Comment: Yes, it will. It applicable when you have a small team.

Comment: This is a very difficult and error prone workflow. Just create personal branches and merge them as needed.

For any git novice reading this... do not follow this approach, no matter how small your team is.