# dividing a project Repository

Tags: git, github, branch

I want to differentiate a repository into different levels

- For development
- For testing and
- For implementation etc.

One solution I found is branching, but there will be issues when merging two branches.

Is there any effective ways, please let me know.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with having your source and test code in a single repository.  Can you explain why you think you need multiple repos here?

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen  Hi,i need to divide the project into levels,once i completed some modifications in my project and  i would like to transfer the commited files to  a new Repo or branch whatever for testing purposes.Then i can continue my development in same Repo or branch.Same way testing team will forward files to bug(Repo/branch) and the non bug files to Deployment(Repo/Branch).This kind of division i m expecting. The advantage of this type leveling is that if anyone going to rectify bugs,i will clone the bug (Repo/branch) to them.which will be eazy.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the nature of levels.

- if they are all related to the codebase, they should all be in the same repo, same branch.
- if they are related to the development lifecycle (dev, QA, staging, production), the same codebase can be duplicated in different repositories.

Branches are more for isolating different parallel development efforts.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your help.This is what i really  meant......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865283/proper-git-workflow-scheme-with-multiple-developers-working-on-same-task

Comment: @krishnanunniR ",once i completed some modifications in my project and i would like to transfer the commited files to a new Repo or branch whatever for testing purposes": As I say in my answer, you can simply push your work to a dedicated repo.