# Continuous Integration Perhaps?

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket

I have a desired need, but I'm not totally sure where to look to.

I use BitBucket.org for my private development of Websites, and my desired effect that I'd like to do is this:

1. I work on feature/ and bug/ branches exclusively
2. Whenever I pull in code to my master (via Pull Request), I want something to trigger:
3. I would like the contents of the master branch to be uploaded to a server (perhaps via FTP?) automatically (even better: just the changes that occurred)

is this something that technology like Jenkins can do? (I don't know anything about CI, it just seems to sound like the thing I'm looking for)

Comment: Do you use only one branch i.e. the master? Also are you sure you would like to automatically upload when you pull? How about when you push?

Comment: No, I work on Feature, Bug, and Issue branches excursively, which all get PR'd into a Release branch, and then Pull Request the Release branch into master when they're ready to be apart of the build. 

Having an automatic upload of just the changes would indeed be useful :)

Comment: Maybe haqve a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18899910/202725

Answer (score 0):

CI is useful for building and testing each commit. The functionality you're talking about should be built into BitBucket, using Hooks if necessary (the gear icon on the repo page). [Here's the docs for Hooks.](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Manage+Bitbucket+hooks)