# Github - How to npm install a repo that is forked to another repo?

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I am having difficulty installing a repo [Pm2 fix](https://github.com/sbleon/pm2/tree/fix-namespace-cli-option) which is forked to the original [Pm2 original](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2).

I have two question

1. How can I npm install the pm2 fix using npm?
2. After I have installed the pm2 fix using npm - am I able to still do npm update pm2 (original) if its being forked? If not, how can I be able to update the original pm2 repo if I install a pm2 fix from another repo that is being forked to the original one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The install from a git is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17509669/1318694) and [for a specific branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39732501/1318694):

```
npm install git+https://github.com/sbleon/pm2#fix-namespace-cli-option
```

Note that some modules with build processes might not work from git.

To keep up to date you would need to maintain your own fork of sbleon/pm2#fix-namespace-cli-option that [merges in changes from the PM2 main branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758915/keeping-a-branch-up-to-date-with-master). In this case from a remote master branch.

Comment: Oh alright, in that caseit make sense. What would you suggest to do? Basically the only change I need to is this part https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/compare/master...sbleon:fix-namespace-cli-option which is a really small code. Im not sure if its "allowed" to install from the pm2 original repo and then modify the code? Or what would you suggest be?

Comment: You will tend to lose local changes on a `yarn` or `npm` command that modifies pm2 so it's not a great solution. have you submitted the issue/pr to pm2?

Comment: Yes there is a PR but waiting for merge https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/pull/4791